# "Открыто / закрыто" в админ-панели сайта

Tags: jquery, css, css3, анимация

На сайте есть график работы, который заполняется в админ-панели сайта вручную.

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Понедельник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Вторник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Среда:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Четверг:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Пятница:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik current"><b>Суббота:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Воскресение:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать статус "открыто" или "закрыто", исходя от графика и текущего времени.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
// Получаем текущую дату и время
let oCurrDate = new Date();
// Получаем элемент с текущим днём недели
let oCurrDay = $(".calendarik").eq(oCurrDate.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : oCurrDate.getDay() - 1);
// Подсвечиваем текущий день недели
oCurrDay.addClass("current");
// Парсим часы работы в тексте пункта
let aPartTime = oCurrDay.text().match(/(\d+)/gi);
// Получаем текущий час
let nHour = oCurrDate.getHours();
// Создаём блок для надписи о статусе
let oStatus = $("<span>");
// Если текущий час попадает в рабочий промежуток,
// тогда устанавливаем нужный текст с нужным цветом
if (nHour >= aPartTime[0] && nHour < aPartTime[2]) {
  oStatus.css("color", "green").html("ОТКРЫТО");
} else {
  oStatus.css("color", "red").html("ЗАКРЫТО");
}
// Отображаем статус около текущего дня
oCurrDay.append(oStatus);
```

```css
.calendarik { font: bold 18px "Arial", sans-serif; color: #555; }

.current { color: #07e; }

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.4em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font: bold 1em "Courier New", monospace;
  animation: pulse 1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 100% { letter-spacing: 0px; text-align: left; }
  25%, 76% { letter-spacing: 0.3em; text-align: left; }
  26%, 75% { letter-spacing: 0.3em; text-align: right; }
  50% { letter-spacing: 0px; text-align: right; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Понедельник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Вторник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Среда:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Четверг:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Пятница:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Суббота:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item calendarik"><b>Воскресение:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: такая славная гусеница получилась :-) Вам не занимать фантазии

Comment: @Alexandr_TT на ходу пришло в голову - дёшево и сердито))

Comment: проблемка, если поставить 11:00 - 01:00. пишет закрыто