# Анимация новогодней ёлочки

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, анимация

### *Наступает Новый год!*

Хорошо бы поднять настроение себе и другим. 
Копировать и рассылать открыточки с красивыми картинками и гифками, скаченными из сети, уже как-то не интересно.

Хочется чего-то необычного, яркого, праздничного, которое есть только у тебя и которое можно подарить близкому человеку со словами,- "Я сделал это для тебя!"
или оставить  у себя с чувством удовлетворения и гордости :-)

Идея сделать новогодний конкурс анимаций принадлежит @Hamster

Вот и рисунок, который она дала для образца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрите, как и в любой другой новогодней открытке, тут есть потенциал для всевозможных  анимаций.

Например:

- Лучи от звезды.

Можно легко сделать с помощью `stroke-dasharray` для широкой строки. Добавить радиальный градиент, анимацию вращения строки и перемещения градиента.

- Снежинки

Нарисовать  в CSS или в SVG многие смогут и далее за анимировать размеры, вращение, падение снежинок.

- Елочка
  Перемигивание гирлянд, легкое покачивание и кручение елочных игрушек, бенгальские огни и т.д и т.п
- Анимация фразы - **С Новым 2019 годом!**

  движение фразы и/или покачивание, обводка, появление букв
- Анимация новогодних персонажей,- белочки, зайчики :) Дед мороз и
  снегурочка

Можно делать весь вышеперечисленный список анимаций, можно реализовать один пункт или несколько.

Главное условие - картинки можно брать любые или рисовать свои, но анимация должна быть своя, никакого копи-паста!

*Конкурс завершился.*

### Поздравляю победителя @Misha Saidov

Благодаря вашим работам дорогие участники, конкурс получился интересным, ярким, запоминающимся. Мы вместе узнали имена новых участников, которые сразу, с ходу ворвались в конкурс и сделали очень крутые работы.
Все работы сделаны на высоком уровне и каждая по своему интересна и хороша.

Comment: А вот елочка от @Grundy https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/pqPMqo , а то ему лень ответ писать)))

Comment: Аж сложно выбрать, всем проставил +1. Красота. Глаз радует

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, за ответ `-150` :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, тут предупредила https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat )

Comment: @HamSter Ооо, да ладно :) я думал, код впустую писал :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Просто все ответы очень хороши :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**ВНИМАНИЕ! Ёлка не идеальна и только для современных браузеров и только в качестве примера!**

[**ПРИМЕР НА CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/qLjNKW?editors=1100).

*Скомпилированный код не вмещается в ответ на so.

---

**Технологии:** `pug`, `sass/scss`, `svg`

---

### ЗАДАЧА 1. ЁЛОЧКА

Хотелось сделать ёлочку с большими звездочками по середине и равномерным уменьшением к краям т.е. задать необходимые для этого условия в `pug` и `scss` файлах.

**Код от участника [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy):**

**pug:**

```
mixin row(n)
  if n == 1
    i(class = 'c-'+n)
  else
    i(class = 'c-'+n)
    +row(n-2)
    i(class = 'c-'+n)

.box
  .tree
    - var n = -1;
    while n++ < 6
      .x
        +row(2*n +1)
```

**scss:**

```
@for $j from 1 through $n {
  .c-#{$j} {
    width:  (21 - $j) + 0px;
    height: (21 - $j) + 0px;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/pqPMqo?editors=1100)

**Скомпилированный код:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #4a5c12;
}
.x {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.tree {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
i {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
path {
  fill: #fff;
}
.tree {
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 230px;
}
.tree i {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.c-1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-2 {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 19px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-3 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-4 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-5 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-6 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-7 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-8 {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-9 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-10 {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-11 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-12 {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 9px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-13 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  line-height: 8px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-14 {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  line-height: 7px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-15 {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  line-height: 6px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-16 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  line-height: 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-17 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  line-height: 4px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-18 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  line-height: 3px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-19 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  line-height: 2px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.c-20 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="tree">
    <div class="x"><i class="c-1"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-5"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-7"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-9"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-9"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-11"></i><i class="c-9"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-9"></i><i class="c-11"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="x"><i class="c-13"></i><i class="c-11"></i><i class="c-9"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-1"></i><i class="c-3"></i><i class="c-5"></i><i class="c-7"></i><i class="c-9"></i><i class="c-11"></i><i class="c-13"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Пришлось обратится за помощью, но потом и меня осенила собственная идея:**

**pug:**

```
-var x = 7
  .tree
    - for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)
      .x
        .inc
          - for (var a = 0; a < i; a++)
            svg
        .mid
          svg
        .dec
          - for (var b = i; b < 2*i; b++)
            svg
```

**scss:**

```
.inc {
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
}    

@for $i from 1 through $n/2  {    
  .tree svg:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    width:  $w/$n/$i + 0px;
    height: $w/$n/$i + 0px;   
  }  
}
```

Получилось не так изящно. Смысл в том, что создаю строки `.x`, в каждой строке 3 блока `.inc` (по возрастанию), `.dec` (по убыванию для его реализации в стилях задаю `flex-row: row-reverse`) и `.mid` (серединка).

---

### ЗАДАЧА 2. СНЕГ

Признаюсь честно, за основу был взят плагин [magic-snowflakes](https://github.com/hcodes/snowflakes), но код `js` преобразован в `scss`:

**pug:**

```
.snowflakes
    -var snow = 15
      - for (var i = 0; i < snow; i++)
        span
          i
```

**scss:**

```
@for $i from 1 through $snow-n {    
  .snowflakes span:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: random(1) + 0s;
    animation-duration: randomNum(10, 30) + 0s;
    left: random(100) + 0%;
    margin-top: -1*random(1)*$snow-w + 0px;
    width: $snow-w + 0px;
    height: $snow-w + 0px;
    z-index: 10099;
    opacity: random(1);

    i {
      animation-name: snowflake_x_#{$i};
      animation-delay: random(1) + 0s;
    }
  }  
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/PXjdda?editors=1100)

---

### ЗАДАЧА 3. НАДПИСЬ (Handwriting)

За пример были взяты работы с codepen: [пример1](https://codepen.io/munkholm/pen/EaZJQE),[пример2](https://codepen.io/marinamcpeak/pen/XYNdvd). Перепробовав все возможные варианты:

- Открываем adobe illustrator
- Пишем любой текст, задаем необходимый шрифт, размер
- Выбираем слой текст и жмем: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> или `Type -> Create outlines`
- Это все будет наш `clip-path`. Блокируем этот слой.
- Создаем новый слой или группу слоев.
- Выбираем карандаш и аккуратно (на сколько это возможно) прорисовываем каждую букву по отдельности.
- Это будет наш `stroke` который мы будем анимировать.
- Сохраняем в `svg` вставляем в `html(pug)` код.

Анимация заключается в изменении значения `stroke-dashoffset`:

```
path {
  stroke-width: 7; 
  animation: dash 8s linear forwards infinite; 
  stroke-dasharray: 2200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2200;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2200;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

При этом важно задать `stroke-width` такой, чтобы полностью заполнить букву.

Получаем: [codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/OrjjPm?editors=1100)

**P.S:** буквы обрисовала не аккуратно, поэтому есть заметные изъяны).

---

### Итого:

[**ПРИМЕР НА CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/qLjNKW?editors=1100).

❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄

> С наступающим Новым Годом! Мира всем и добра!

❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄ ❄

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, какие еще 2 попытки?)))) Тут итак неделю убила на одну эту! Конкурс твой, я вообще не претендую ни на что! Жалко что тут так мало ответов, было бы приятно увидеть несколько просто зеленых треугольников с шарами, чем 2-3 но сложных

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поняла) ... хотела еще шарики новогодние сделать, но что-то уже лень))) дедушку мороза ... есть идея, может быть уже после нового года

Comment: Поделись репутацией своей, и она к тебе еще не раз вернется :) Держи 150! Круто получилось!

Comment: @VerNick, СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 63):

Это бандл из моих предыдущих ответов.

Как видите, код стал модульным - можно на его базе собрать любого Франкенштейна. Также код вариативный везде, где только можно - любой коэффициент можно поменять, чтобы добиться желаемого результата и резиновый (на сколько смог). Повторюсь, что я не умею в векторную графику и канвас, поэтому накодил все на дивах и картинках. Разверните на всю страницу, если сильно сплющит.

**UPD 0**: Добавил покачивание снежинок, изменил некоторые коэффициенты и сменил изображение звездочек елки на более нейтральное.

**UPD 1**: Добавил **текст** и заанимировал.

**UPD 2**: **Санта!** Он будет появляться и махать рукой с разных сторон экрана. Думаю, далее будут только какие-то минорные правки, а так - это финалочка ;)

**UPD 3**: Оптимизация. Теперь все делает один цикл (вместо 4-х, как раньше). Открытка стала чуть более снисходительна на старт: картинки появляются только после полной загрузки и убрал ненужный тут `$(document).ready()` Скрипт по-прежнему костыль :)

```js
const randomBetween = (a, b) => {
  return (a + (Math.random() * (b - a)));
}
const randomArr = (arr) => {
  return arr[Math.round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))];
}

const params = {
  snowflakes: {
    amount: 15,
    duration: {
      min: 3,
      max: 8
    },
    size: {
      min: 10,
      max: 32
    },
    src: [
      "http://pngimg.com/uploads/snowflakes/snowflakes_PNG7578.png",
      "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/2/27/Snowflake.png/revision/latest?cb=20121220012520",
      "https://latxikadelacerveza.es/wp-content/plugins/christmas-panda/assets/images/snowflake_5.png"
    ],
    container: "#snowflakes"
  },
  tree: {
    amount: 300,
    stretching: 1.4,
    movement: 5,
    src: "https://i.imgur.com/pPjPR8q.png",
    duration: {
      min: 5,
      max: 50
    },
    size: {
      min: 20,
      max: 30
    },
    container: "#tree"
  },
  rays: {
    amount: 40,
    duration: 30,
    width: 3,
    height: 100,
    perspective: 150,
    color: "rgba(215,249,111,1)",
    container: "#rays"
  },
  text: {
    text: "С Новым 2019 годом!",
    duration: 30,
    width: 3,
    height: 100,
    perspective: 150,
    color: "rgba(215,249,111,1)",
    container: "#text"
  }
}


let totalAmount = 0;
for (let key in params) {
  let amount = params[key].amount;
  totalAmount += typeof amount === "number" ? amount : 0;
}

for (let i = 0; i < totalAmount; i++) {
  if (i < params.snowflakes.amount) {
    let snowflake = $("<img src='" + randomArr(params.snowflakes.src) + "'>");
    let randomSize = randomBetween(params.snowflakes.size.min, params.snowflakes.size.max);
    snowflake.css({
      "width": randomSize + "px",
      "height": randomSize + "px",
      "left": randomBetween(0, 100) + "%",
      "animation-duration": randomBetween(params.snowflakes.duration.min, params.snowflakes.duration.max) + "s"
    });

    $(params.snowflakes.container).append(snowflake);
  }



  if (i < params.tree.amount) {
    if (i === 0) {
      $(params.tree.container).append("<img class='main' src='" + params.tree.src + "'>");
    }
    let star = $("<img src='" + params.tree.src + "'>");
    let top = randomBetween(0, randomBetween(70, 100));
    let randomSize = (randomBetween(params.tree.size.min, params.tree.size.max) * (top + 10) / 100);
    star.css({
      "width": randomSize + "px",
      "height": randomSize + "px",
      "left": "calc(50% - " + (Math.sin(top / params.tree.stretching) * top) + "px)",
      "top": top + "%",
      "animation-duration": randomBetween(params.tree.duration.min, params.tree.duration.max) + "s",
      "transform-origin": (50 + randomBetween(-params.tree.movement, params.tree.movement)) + "% " + (50 + randomBetween(-params.tree.movement, params.tree.movement)) + "%"
    });

    $(params.tree.container).append(star);
  }



  if (i < params.rays.amount) {
    if (i === 0) {
      $(params.rays.container).css({
        "animation-duration": params.rays.duration + "s",
        width: params.rays.height * 2 + "px",
        height: params.rays.height * 2 + "px"
      });
      window.alignRays = () => {
        let mainStar = $(params.tree.container).find(".main");
        $(params.rays.container).css("top", (mainStar.offset().top - params.rays.height) + (mainStar.height() / 2) + "px");
      }
      $(window).on("resize", window.alignRays);
    }
    let ray = $("<div></div>");
    ray.css({
      "width": params.rays.width + "px",
      "height": params.rays.height + "px",
      "transform": "perspective(" + params.rays.perspective + "px) rotateZ(" + (360 / params.rays.amount * i) + "deg) rotateX(-60deg)",
      "background": "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%," + params.rays.color + " 100%)"
    });

    $(params.rays.container).append(ray);
  }



  if (i < params.text.text.length) {
    let char = params.text.text.substr(i, 1);
    char = char === " " ? "&nbsp;" : char;
    let charElem = $("<div>" + char + "</div>");
    charElem.css("animation-delay", (i / 10) + "s");
    $(params.text.container).append(charElem);
  }



  if (i === totalAmount - 1) {
    $("#root").css("display", "block");
    window.alignRays();
    let selector = [];
    for (let key in params) {
      let container = params[key].container;
      selector.push(typeof container === "string" ? container + " > img" : "");
    }
    selector = selector.join(",");
    $(selector).css("display", "none");
    $(selector).on("load", (e) => $(e.target).css("display", ""));
  }
}


let santa = $("#santa");
santa.css("display", "none");
santa.on("load", (e) => $(e.target).css("display", ""));
setInterval(() => {
  let side = ["right", "left"][Math.round(Math.random())];
  let randTop = Math.round(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - 220));
  santa.css("top", randTop + "px");
  santa.addClass(side);
  setTimeout(() => {
    santa.removeClass();
  }, 2000);
}, 4000);
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 30%, #a1c920 10%, #1e2708 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

#santa {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 12;
  top: 20px;
  width: 135px;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#santa.left {
  animation-name: santa-left;
  display: block;
  left: -135px;
}

#santa.right {
  animation-name: santa-right;
  display: block;
  right: -135px;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 390px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#text>div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Pacifico;
  animation-name: text;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
}

#rays {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
  animation-name: rotate;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 0) 70%);
}

#rays>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

#snowflakes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 7;
}

#snowflakes>img {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: drop;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#tree {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 270px;
  z-index: 9;
}

#tree>img.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#tree>img {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: shake;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    opacity: .7;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes text {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: .4;
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(50deg) scale(.5);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(.7);
    opacity: .7;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(150deg) scale(1);
    opacity: .4;
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(130deg) scale(.6);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(60deg) scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(120deg) scale(.4);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(300deg) scale(.1);
    opacity: .7;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(240deg) scale(.5);
    opacity: .6;
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(200deg) scale(.9);
    opacity: .3;
  }
}

@keyframes santa-right {
  from,
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
  }
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-65deg);
  }
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.santa-right {
  animation-name: santa-right;
}

@keyframes santa-left {
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    transform: rotate(75deg);
  }
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
    transform: rotate(65deg);
  }
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.santa-left {
  -webkit-animation-name: santa-left;
  animation-name: santa-left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="root">
  <div id="tree"></div>
  <div id="snowflakes"></div>
  <div id="rays"></div>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <img id="santa" class="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/Fyyiz3d.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Очень круто!!!!!!!

Comment: @HamSter awww спасибо большое!

Answer (score 49):

Новогодняя сценка создана без использования каких-либо ресурсов.

> ОТСТОРОЖНО, сниппет может вызвать странные эффекты, тут процессор почти ничем не занят, весь алгоритм реализован во фрагментном шейдере и если у Вас нет видеокарты то извиняйте...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script>
    var fragCode =`
    
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec3 eye;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float time;

// https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm
// distance functions

float dot2( in vec2 v ) {
    return dot(v,v);
}

float sdCappedCone( in vec3 p, in float h, in float r1, in float r2 ){
    vec2 q = vec2( length(p.xz), p.y );
    vec2 k1 = vec2(r2,h);
    vec2 k2 = vec2(r2-r1,2.0*h);
    vec2 ca = vec2(q.x-min(q.x,(q.y < 0.0)?r1:r2), abs(q.y)-h);
    vec2 cb = q - k1 + k2*clamp( dot(k1-q,k2)/dot2(k2), 0.0, 1.0 );
    float s = (cb.x < 0.0 && ca.y < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    return s*sqrt( min(dot2(ca),dot2(cb)) );
}

// vertical
float sdCylinder( vec3 p, vec2 h ){
  vec2 d = abs(vec2(length(p.xz),p.y)) - h;
  return min(max(d.x,d.y),0.0) + length(max(d,0.0));
}

float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s ){
    return length(p)-s;
}

float sdPlane( vec3 p , float down){
 return p.y - down;
}

float plane(vec3 p, vec3 n, float offs) {
    return dot(p, n) - offs;
}


// distance functions operations

float opS( float d1, float d2 ){
    return max(-d2,d1);
}

vec2 opU( vec2 d1, vec2 d2 ){
 return (d1.x<d2.x) ? d1 : d2;
}

vec3 opRep( vec3 p, vec3 c ){
    return mod(p,c)-0.5*c;
}

float opSmoothU( float d1, float d2, float k ) {
    float h = clamp( 0.5 + 0.5*(d2-d1)/k, 0.0, 1.0 );
    return mix( d2, d1, h ) - k*h*(1.0-h);
}

vec2 rotate(vec2 p, float ang) {
    float c = cos(ang), s = sin(ang);
    return vec2(p.x*c - p.y*s, p.x*s + p.y*c);
}

vec2 repeatAng(vec2 p, float n) {
    float ang = 2.0*3.14/n;
    float sector = floor(atan(p.x, p.y)/ang + 0.5);
    p = rotate(p, sector*ang);
    return p;
}

///

const float PI =3.141592;
const float PI2 = 6.2831853;

const float maxd = 256.0; //Max depth
float nearestD = maxd;
vec3 color = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

float flakes(vec3 p) {

    const float snowflakeMaxDist = 20.0;
    if ( (abs(p.x) > snowflakeMaxDist) ||
         (abs(p.y) > snowflakeMaxDist) ||
         (abs(p.z) > snowflakeMaxDist) )

         return 9999.9;

    float snowPush = 0.25*time;

    p.x += snowPush*-3.0;
    p.y += snowPush*1.5;
    p.z += snowPush*-0.25;

    const float modDist = 2.0;

    float stepX = floor(p.x/modDist);
    float stepY = floor(p.y/modDist);
    float stepZ = floor(p.z/modDist);

    vec3 flakeP = vec3(
        mod(p.x,modDist),
        mod(p.y,modDist),
        mod(p.z,modDist)
    );

    vec3 flakePos = vec3(modDist*0.5);
    flakePos.x += sin(snowPush+stepY*1.0)*(2.0/5.0)*modDist;
    flakePos.y += sin(snowPush+stepZ*1.3)*(2.0/5.0)*modDist;
    flakePos.z += sin(snowPush+stepX*1.7)*(2.0/5.0)*modDist;
    return sdSphere(flakeP- flakePos, 0.03);
}

// noise
float hash(vec3 p) {
    p  = fract( p*0.3183099+.1 );
 p *= 17.0;
    return fract( p.x*p.y*p.z*(p.x+p.y+p.z) );
}
float noise( in vec3 x ){
    vec3 p = floor(x);
    vec3 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    return mix(mix(mix( hash(p+vec3(0,0,0)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,0,0)),f.x),
                   mix( hash(p+vec3(0,1,0)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,1,0)),f.x),f.y),
               mix(mix( hash(p+vec3(0,0,1)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,0,1)),f.x),
                   mix( hash(p+vec3(0,1,1)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,1,1)),f.x),f.y),f.z);
}

float noise( vec2 x ){
    return noise(vec3(x, 0.));
}

const float VERY_FAR = 1e11;

float ground(vec3 p){
    float d = -0.50 ;
    p.y += noise(p)*.33 ;
    d = sdPlane(p, d);
    return d;
}

vec2 star(vec3 p) {
    p.y -=1.5;
    p.xy = repeatAng(p.xy, 5.0);            // 3. Clone five cornders radially about Z axis
    p.xz = abs(p.xz);                       // 2. Symmetrical about XoY and ZoY
    vec3 n = vec3(0.5, 0.25, 0.8);
    float d = plane(p, normalize(n), 0.065);  // 1. A plane cutting the corner of X+Y+Z+
    return vec2(d, .900 );
}

vec2 green(vec3 p) {
    float d = VERY_FAR;
    float k = .12;
    d =              sdCappedCone( p - vec3(.0, .99, .0), .4, 0.45, .0);
    d = opSmoothU(d, sdCappedCone( p - vec3(.0, .55, .0), .5, 0.55, .0), k);
    d = opSmoothU(d, sdCappedCone( p - vec3(.0, .11, .0), .6, 0.65, .0), k);
    return vec2( d, 0.090 );
}

vec2 trunk(vec3 p) {
    float d = VERY_FAR;
    d = sdCylinder(p-vec3(.0, -.5,.0), vec2(0.1, 0.6));
    return vec2( d, 0.000 );
}

vec2 toy(vec3 p, float col) {
    float d = VERY_FAR;
    d = sdSphere(p, 0.07);
    return vec2( d, col );
}

vec2 toys(vec3 p) {
    vec2 res = vec2(VERY_FAR, -1);

    float r = .42;
    float h = -0.57;
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3(-r, h, -r), 0.990) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3(-r, h,  r), 0.099) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( r, h, -r), 0.999) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( r, h,  r), 0.555) );

    r = .3;
    h = 0.5;
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3(-r, h, -r), 0.990) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3(-r, h,  r), 0.099) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( r, h, -r), 0.999) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( r, h,  r), 0.555) );

    r = .5;
    h = -0.05;
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3(-r, h, 0.), 0.990) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( 0, h, -r), 0.099) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( r, h, 0.), 0.999) );
    res = opU( res, toy(p-vec3( 0, h, r), 0.555) );

    return res;
}


vec2 tree(vec3 p) {
    vec2 res = vec2(VERY_FAR, -1);

    res = opU( res, green(p) );
    res = opU( res, trunk(p) );
    res = opU( res, star(p) );
    res = opU( res, toys(p) );

    return res;
}

float snowmans(vec3 p) {

    // mirror 3
    p.xz = repeatAng(p.xz, 3.0);
    p.xz = abs(p.xz);

    float k = .12;
    float d =        sdSphere( p - vec3(1.5,  0.7, 3.0), .2);
    d = opSmoothU(d, sdSphere( p - vec3(1.5,  0.2, 3.0), .3), k);
    d = opSmoothU(d, sdSphere( p - vec3(1.5, -0.4, 3.0), .4), k);
    return d;
}

float snowfall(vec3 p) {
    vec3 q = vec3(mod(p.x, 3.0) - 1.5, p.yz);
    return sdSphere( q - vec3(1.5,  0.7, 3.0), .02);
}

vec2 snow(vec3 p) {

    float k = .12;
    float d = ground(p);
    d = opSmoothU(d, snowmans( p ), k);
    d = opSmoothU( d, flakes(p), k );
    return vec2( d, .999 );
}

vec2 snowmans_accesories(vec3 p) {

    // mirror 3
    p.xz = repeatAng(p.xz, 3.0);
    p.xz = abs(p.xz);

    float k = .12;
    vec2 res =     vec2(sdSphere( p - vec3(1.50,  0.70, 3.20), .02), 0.00 );
    res = opU(res, vec2(sdSphere( p - vec3(1.44,  0.75, 3.18), .02), 0.00 ));
    res = opU(res, vec2(sdSphere( p - vec3(1.56,  0.75, 3.18), .02), 0.00 ));
    res = opU(res, vec2(sdSphere( p - vec3(1.50,  0.25, 3.30), .02), 0.00 ));
    res = opU(res, vec2(sdSphere( p - vec3(1.50, -0.40, 3.40), .02), 0.00 ));
    return res;
}


vec2 map(vec3 p) {
    vec2 res = vec2(VERY_FAR, -1);

    res = opU( res, snow(p) );
    res = opU( res, snowmans_accesories(p) );
    res = opU( res, tree(p) );


    return res;
}

// ray direction

vec3 rayDirection(float fieldOfView, vec2 size) {
    vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy - size / 2.0;
    float z = size.y / tan(radians(fieldOfView) / 2.0);
    return normalize(vec3(xy, -z));
}


// compute view matrix

mat4 viewMatrix(vec3 eye, vec3 center, vec3 up) {
 vec3 f = normalize(center - eye);
 vec3 s = normalize(cross(f, up));
 vec3 u = cross(s, f);
 return mat4(
  vec4(s, 0.0),
  vec4(u, 0.0),
  vec4(-f, 0.0),
  vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
 );
}


// ro - ray origin
// rd - ray direction
vec2 castRay( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd ) {

    float tmin = 1.0;
    float tmax = 32.0;
    float t = tmin;
    float m = -1.0;

    for ( int i=0; i<128; i++ ) {
     float precis = 0.0001*t;
     vec2 res = map( ro+rd*t );
        if ( res.x<precis || t>tmax )
            break;
        t += res.x/1.4;
     m = res.y;
    }

    if ( t>tmax )
        m=-1.0;

    return vec2( t, m );
}

// estimate normal at point
// http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/normalsSDF/normalsSDF.htm

const float NORMAL_EPSILON = 0.0005;

vec3 estimateNormal(vec3 pos) {
    vec2 e = vec2(1.0,-1.0)*0.5773*NORMAL_EPSILON;
    return normalize( e.xyy*map( pos + e.xyy ).x +
       e.yyx*map( pos + e.yyx ).x +
       e.yxy*map( pos + e.yxy ).x +
       e.xxx*map( pos + e.xxx ).x );
}


const vec3 K_a = vec3(.3, .2, .2);
const vec3 K_d = vec3(.2, .4, .7);
const vec3 K_s = vec3(.1, .1, .1);

const float shininess = 3.5;

const vec3 lightIntensity = vec3(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);

vec3 phongContribForLight(vec3 k_d, vec3 k_s, float alpha, vec3 p, vec3 eye,
                          vec3 lightPos, vec3 lightIntensity) {

    vec3 N = estimateNormal(p);
    vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - p);
    vec3 V = normalize(eye - p);
    vec3 R = normalize(reflect(-L, N));

    float dotLN = dot(L, N);
    float dotRV = dot(R, V);


    if (dotLN < 0.0) {
        // Light not visible from this point on the surface
        return vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    if (dotRV < 0.0) {
        // Light reflection in opposite direction as viewer, apply only diffuse
        // component
        return lightIntensity * (k_d * dotLN);
    }

    return lightIntensity * (k_d * dotLN + k_s * pow(dotRV, alpha));
}


vec3 phongIllumination(vec3 k_a, vec3 k_d, vec3 k_s, float alpha, vec3 p, vec3 eye, vec3 materialColor) {

    vec3 color = materialColor * k_a;
    color += phongContribForLight(k_d, k_s, alpha, p, eye, lightPos, lightIntensity);

    return color;
}


vec3 decodeMaterialColor(float material) {

    float r = material * 10.;
    r = r - fract(r);
    r = r/10.;

    float g = material * 100. - r * 100.;
    g = g - fract(g);
    g = g/10.;

    float b = material * 1000. - r * 1000. - g * 100.;
    b = b - fract(b);
    b = b/10.;

    return vec3(r, g, b);
}

vec3 phong(vec3 p, vec3 eye, float material) {
    vec3 materialColor = decodeMaterialColor(material);
    return phongIllumination(K_a, K_d, K_s, shininess, p, eye, materialColor);
}

// http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/rmshadows/rmshadows.htm
float softShadow( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, in float mint, in float tmax ){
 float res = 1.0;
    float t = mint;
    for( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
    {
  float h = map( ro + rd*t ).x;
        res = min( res, 8.0*h/t );
        t += clamp( h, 0.02, 0.10 );
        if( res<0.005 || t>tmax ) break;
    }
    return clamp( res, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

// ambient occlusion
float ao( in vec3 pos, in vec3 nor ){
 float occ = 0.0;
    float sca = 1.0;
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        float hr = 0.01 + 0.12*float(i)/4.0;
        vec3 aopos =  nor * hr + pos;
        float dd = map( aopos ).x;
        occ += -(dd-hr)*sca;
        sca *= 0.95;
    }
    return clamp( 1.0 - 3.0*occ, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

void main(void) {
 vec3 direction = rayDirection(60.0, resolution);
    mat4 viewToWorld = viewMatrix(eye, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    vec3 worldDir = (viewToWorld * vec4(direction, 0.0)).xyz;
    vec2 dist = castRay(eye, worldDir);
    if (dist.x > 24.) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
    } else {
        vec3 pt = eye + dist.x * worldDir;
        vec3 nor = estimateNormal( pt );
        float occ = ao( pt, nor );
        float shadow = softShadow( pt, normalize(lightPos-pt), 0.1, 22.2);
        vec3 color = phong(pt, eye, dist.y)*sqrt(occ);
        color += color * shadow;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
}
    `;
</script>

<script>
function GLx() {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

    return {
        gl: gl,
        buffer: buffer,
        program: program,
        resize: resize
    };

    function program(vs, fs) {
        var pid = gl.createProgram(); // program id
        shader(vs, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        shader(fs, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.linkProgram(pid);

        var p = {
            uniform: uniform,
            attribute: attribute,
            use: use
        };

        return p;

        function use() {
            gl.useProgram(pid);
            return p;
        }

        function attribute(name, count) {
            var al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, name);

            return {
                bind: bind
            };

            function bind(buffer) {
                buffer.bind();
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, count, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);
            }
        }

        function uniform(type, name) {
            var ul = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, name);

            return {
                set: set
            };

            function set(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
                gl['uniform' + type](ul, v1, v2, v3, v4);
            }
        }

        function shader(src, type) {
            var sid = gl.createShader(type);
            gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
            gl.compileShader(sid);
            var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
            if (message.length > 0){
                console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
                    return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
                }).join('\n'));
                throw message;
            }
            gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
        }
    }

    function buffer(data) {
        var array = new Float32Array(data);
        var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        var type = gl.ARRAY_BUFFER;
        gl.bindBuffer(type, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(type, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bindBuffer(type, data = null);

        return {
            bind: bind
        };

        function bind() {
            gl.bindBuffer(type, buffer);
        }
    }

    function resize() {
        var c = canvas;
        if (c.clientWidth !== c.width || c.clientHeight !== c.height) {
            c.width = c.clientWidth;
            c.height = c.clientHeight;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// full-screen-triangle with webgl

function FullScreenTriangle(fragCode) {

    var glx = GLx();

    var vertices = glx.buffer([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);

    var vertCode =
        `attribute vec2 coords;
     void main(void) {
       gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
     }`;

    glx.triangleProgram = glx.program(vertCode, 'precision highp float;' + fragCode).use();
    glx.triangleProgram.attribute("coords", 2).bind(vertices);

    glx.draw = function () {
        var gl = glx.gl;
        glx.resize();
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    };

    return glx;
}


var Mouse3D = (function(){

    var theta = 0;
    var phi = 0;
    var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var radius = 7;
    var dragStartMousePosition, dragStartPhi, dragStartTheta;
    var callback;
    var mouse3d = {
        init: init,
        eye: [0, 0, radius],
        callback: function (cb) {
            callback = cb;
        }
    };

    return mouse3d;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        window.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheel, false);
    }

    function mouseMove(event) {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;
        mouse = event;
        if (dragStartMousePosition) {
            rotate();
        }
    }

    function updateCameraPosition() {
        mouse3d.eye[0] = radius * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
        mouse3d.eye[1] = radius * Math.sin(phi);
        mouse3d.eye[2] = radius * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
        callback && callback();
    }

    function rotate() {
        var amountX = dragStartMousePosition ? dragStartMousePosition.x - mouse.x : 0;
        var amountZ = mouse.y - dragStartMousePosition.y;
        theta = dragStartTheta + amountX/120;
        phi = dragStartPhi + amountZ/120;
        var limit = Math.PI / 2;
        phi = phi > limit ? limit : phi;
        phi = phi < -limit ? -limit : phi;
        updateCameraPosition();
    }

    function mouseDown(event) {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;
        dragStartPhi = phi;
        dragStartTheta = theta;
        dragStartMousePosition = event;
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        if (event.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;
        rotate();
        dragStartMousePosition = null;
        dragStartPhi = 0;
        dragStartTheta = 0;
    }

    function mouseWheel(e){
        radius *= e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 0.9 : 1.1;
        updateCameraPosition();
    }
})();

Mouse3D.init();

let fst = FullScreenTriangle(fragCode);
let resolution = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('2f', 'resolution');
let lightPos = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('3f', 'lightPos');
let time = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('1f', 'time');
let eye = fst.triangleProgram.uniform('3f', 'eye');
addEventListener('mousemove', drawFrame);
animate();
var started = new Date().getTime();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    drawFrame();
}

function drawFrame() {
    let t = (new Date().getTime() - started)/1000;
    resolution.set(fst.gl.drawingBufferWidth, fst.gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    time.set(t);
    lightPos.set(Math.cos(t/10)*10,10,Math.sin(t/10)*10);
    eye.set(Mouse3D.eye[0], Mouse3D.eye[1], Mouse3D.eye[2]);
    fst.draw();
}

</script>
<style>
body, canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Это все придумано давным давно, однако раньше, трассировка лучей в реальном времени была фантастикой и таким образом создавали статические картинки. сегодня каждый обладатель компьютера с видеокартой может написать фрагментный шейдер, который делает трассировку простеньких (и не очень) сцен в реальном времени.

Для этого потребуются:

- Желание разбираться с математикой
- Много свободного времени
- Видеокарта, у меня gtx1050ti (768 вычислительных ядер) и это мало :(
- Браузер с поддержкой WebGL

Во фрагменте кода приведена уже склеенная версия, исходник на [github gists](https://gist.github.com/strangerintheq/73ad4b97ac498bf7ae607f262d6b6ff5) и [blocks](https://bl.ocks.org/strangerintheq/73ad4b97ac498bf7ae607f262d6b6ff5).

Итак, попробую по-простому описать что тут происходит, т.к. код вы можете и сами почитать.

Для начала WebGL инициализируется таким образом, чтобы нарисовать один треугольник, который покрывает весь экран как на изображении ниже, или как-то иначе, главное вызвать фрагментный шейдер для каждого пикселя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрагментный шейдер делает всю работу.

Перед формированием каждого кадра, из javascript в шейдер передаются некоторые переменные, которые характеризуют сцену, тут это положение наблюдателя в декартовых координатах, размер картинки, и еще для анимации понадобится время.

Конечно перед каждым кадром обновлять все uniform переменные не нужно, но в этом примере я сделал так для простоты кода.

—-

Далее в каждом фрагменте(пикселе) происходит трассировка луча:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нашем случае это raymarching, что про сути есть оптимизация шага трассировки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В отличие от классического представления объектов сцены в виде треугольников, тут используются математические формулы дистанции до поверхностей(так называемые signed distance fields, SDF). Шагая вдоль луча, применяется огромная формула (функция `map(vec3)`), которая вычисляет дистанцию от точки-аргумента до всех объектов в сцене и возвращает минимальную. Дистанция которую вернула эта функция - безопасное расстояние, шагнув на которое, мы точно не во что не упремся.

Собственно это будет длина следующего шага, вдоль луча, и так до тех пор, пока луч не упрется в поверхность.

```
vec2 map(vec3 p) {
    vec2 res = vec2(VERY_FAR, -1);

    res = opU( res, snow(p) );
    res = opU( res, snowmans_accesories(p) );
    res = opU( res, tree(p) );

    return res;
}
```

Изначально результат инициализируется расстоянием очень далеким от наблюдателя, т.е. будущим фоном. -1 выступает в роли идентификатора материала.

Функция `opU` - названа от слов operation и union и предназначена для объединения объектов сцены.

Каждый компонент, объединяемый этой операцией это в свою очередь тоже функция, только описывающая один объект сцены плюс возвращающая вторым компонентом идентификатор(цвет) материала.  Объекты, в свою очередь, состят из более простых примитивов: сфер, цилиндров, кубов, фракталов, поверхностей безье, [чего душе угодно](http://mercury.sexy/hg_sdf/), между которыми возможно всевозможные трансформации, булевые операции итд.

Все вместе это и описывает сцену .

После того, как точка где луч уперся в поверхность найдена - начинается самое сложное и самое интересное, это определение цвета найденной точки.

В этой сцене цвет состоит из нескольких компонентов:

- Цвет поверхности (diffuse)
- Модель освещения по Фонгу([phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading))
- Самозатенение [ambient occlusion](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion)
- Мягкие тени (soft shadows)

Этот список можно было бы продолжать всякими экранными эффектами, компонентами других моделей освещения и чего еще только не напридумывали.

Непосредственно при моделировании никаких сложных примитивов не использовано,
все объекты собраны из

**сфер**

```
float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s ){
    return length(p)-s;
}
```

**плоскостей**

```
// horizontal
float sdPlane( vec3 p , float down){
    return p.y - down;
}

float plane(vec3 p, vec3 n, float offs) {
    return dot(p, n) - offs;
}
```

**усеченных конусов**

```
float sdCappedCone( in vec3 p, in float h, in float r1, in float r2 ){
    vec2 q = vec2( length(p.xz), p.y );
    vec2 k1 = vec2(r2,h);
    vec2 k2 = vec2(r2-r1,2.0*h);
    vec2 ca = vec2(q.x-min(q.x,(q.y < 0.0)?r1:r2), abs(q.y)-h);
    vec2 cb = q - k1 + k2*clamp( dot(k1-q,k2)/dot2(k2), 0.0, 1.0 );
    float s = (cb.x < 0.0 && ca.y < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    return s*sqrt( min(dot2(ca),dot2(cb)) );
}
```

**цилиндра**

```
float sdCylinder( vec3 p, vec2 h ){
    vec2 d = abs(vec2(length(p.xz),p.y)) - h;
    return min(max(d.x,d.y),0.0) + length(max(d,0.0));
}
```

**и шума(noise)**, для создания "сугробов":

```
float hash(vec3 p) {
    p  = fract( p*0.3183099+.1 );
    p *= 17.0;
    return fract( p.x*p.y*p.z*(p.x+p.y+p.z) );
}
float noise( in vec3 x ){
    vec3 p = floor(x);
    vec3 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    return mix(mix(mix( hash(p+vec3(0,0,0)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,0,0)),f.x),
                   mix( hash(p+vec3(0,1,0)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,1,0)),f.x),f.y),
               mix(mix( hash(p+vec3(0,0,1)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,0,1)),f.x),
                   mix( hash(p+vec3(0,1,1)),
                        hash(p+vec3(1,1,1)),f.x),f.y),f.z);
}
```

Так же тут используется отражение и поворот пространства, для создания 6 снеговиков и звезды, операция smoothMin для создания плавных переходов между поверхностями

Upd2: добавил деталей, теперь летит снег и взаимодействует с другим снегом в сцене при помощи `smooth minimum`, двигается источник света, самую актуальную версию смотрите [тут](https://bl.ocks.org/strangerintheq/73ad4b97ac498bf7ae607f262d6b6ff5)

PPS: все происходящее тут можно сильно оптимизировать, начиная от шума, который тут считается каждый раз, его можно либо запечь в текстуру, либо сразу предоставить текстуру шума, затем функция `map()`... для разных частей освещения или эффектов можно использовать различные упрощенные версии `map()` кандидаты на это - построение теней, ambient occlusion, из последнего убрать бы летящий снег, сам raymarching тоже может быть оптимизирован на счет первоначальной трассировки более простых сцен(кубов или сфер в которых вписаны объекты сцены), для уменьшения количества шагов трассировки

PPPS:
Где можно про это почитать:

1. Сайт [Inigo Quilez](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/raymarchingdf/raymarchingdf.htm).
2. Простенький туториал от [Jamie Wong](http://jamie-wong.com/2016/07/15/ray-marching-signed-distance-functions/#signed-distance-functions)
3. Ну и конечно же гуглёж по терминам

   - signed distance field(function), SDF
   - raymarching, raytracing

---

**UPD 31.03.2019: Починил ( правда ценой производительности (: ) артефакты прошлой версии, когда при взгляде сверху появлялись черно-цветные полосы.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ух, класс! Мне очень нравится!

Comment: Вы меня удивили! Мне очень нравится!

Comment: Очень круто! Можете еще добавить снега, и победить в конкурсе :)

Comment: Вау! Вот это скилл!

Comment: пример конечно самый самый но кулер у моего компа начинает психовать со страшной силой ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский спасибо, это видеокарта шумит,  это все функция noise виновата, если строчку с ней убрать будет быстрее намного

Comment: @StrangerintheQ webgl конечно очень интересная техника и прогрессивная  но подходит не ко всем компьютерам ...но ваш ответ лично я бы тоже признал лучшим (хоть копипаст хоть нет)

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский копипаста конечно есть, строительные блоки - функции трассировки, примитивов,  шума, конечно же это не я придумал, но в этом и мощь суммарного интеллекта человечества, мы осознаём чужое и используем по своему, теорема Пифагора это копипаста?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  тут базара нет - пример самый красивый и самый лучший в рамках всего проекта stackoverflow за последние 3 года ... и не достоин награды в 150 а большего ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский третий приз тоже мне достался, так что я не в обиде, хотя конечно эта работа заняла больше времени, но лишь только потому что я параллельно разобрался с некоторыми особенностями создания тел при помощи sdf

Comment: В процессе кручения картинки [возникли ошибки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZgll.png).

Comment: Очень круто выглядит!

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski спасибо) я старался

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  ты здесь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky в целом да, мне на телефон уведомления приходят

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  открой чат и пригласи меня - а то у меня репы не хватает

Comment: @MaximLensky https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91385/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-maximlensky

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Привет Константин Я что-то не понимаю или действительно удален код  полного решения из снипета?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT хай, вроде на месте... он под первой картинкой, в спойлере свернут

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Здравствуйте я анимашку не могу увидеть :(( это все из-за моего процессора как я понял ?

Comment: @Leks какой у Вас браузер и видео карта?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  браузер  google  и видео карта GeForce GT 630

Comment: @Leks странно, должно работать, а ошибки есть в консоли?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  нет,  сперва белый экран, потом картинка статическая, а потом через некоторое время картинка поменялась еще раз :( я думаю это у меня процессор слабый ...

Comment: @Leks тут только видяха нужна, но жирная, можно маленькое окно попробовать

Comment: @Stranger in the Q скорее всего т.к. когда я нажимаю выполнить  код у меня начинает лагать :(

Answer (score 36):

А вот и **Ёлочка**!

Я плох в векторной графике и канвасе, но что-то смыслю в математике, поэтому как смог :) В общем, можно заметить, что есть очень много общего со скриптом снежинок, который я кидал ранее. Соль заключается в том, что позиционированием звездочек полностью занимается js при помощи функции `y=sin(x)*x`, график которой похож на елку. Перевернув эту функцию на 90 градусов можно получить точки расположения звездочек по оси Y. Размер звездочек вариативный, но зависит от смещения сверху: чем ниже, тем больше звезда, как на картинке. Немного визуальных эффектов и вот :) Хорошо себя чувствует при ресайзе, разверните на весь экран, для примера. Не совсем похоже, конечно, но, думаю, имеет место быть.

```js
let params = {
  amount: 800,
  duration: {
    min: 8,
    max: 20
  },
  size: {
    min: 20,
    max: 45
  }
}

const randomBetween = (a, b) => {
  return (a + (Math.random() * (b - a)));
}
const randomArr = (arr) => {
  return arr[Math.round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))];
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < params.amount; i++) {
    let star = $("<img class='star' src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/justdance/images/2/2e/Star.png/revision/latest?cb=20160307193808'>");
    let top = randomBetween(0, randomBetween(50, 100));
    let randomSize = (randomBetween(params.size.min, params.size.max) * top / 100);
    star.css({
      "width": randomSize + "px",
      "height": randomSize + "px",
      "left": "calc(50% - " + (Math.sin(top) * top) + "px)",
      "top": top * 3 + "px",
      "animation-duration": randomBetween(params.duration.min, params.duration.max) + "s",
      "transform-origin": (50 + randomBetween(-15, +15)) + "% " + (50 + randomBetween(-15, 15)) + "%"
    });

    $("#root").append(star);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}

#root {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px white);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-star {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  z-index: 9;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: shake;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(50deg) scale(.5);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(184deg) scale(.7);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(365deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(130deg) scale(.6);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(10deg) scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(46deg) scale(.4);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(.1);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(240deg) scale(.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(200deg) scale(.9);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <img class="main-star" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/justdance/images/2/2e/Star.png/revision/latest?cb=20160307193808">
</div>
```

Comment: С ёлкой фпс упал, жесть.

Comment: Согласен, очень ресурсоемкая елочка, ибо нужно одновременно анимировать 800 звездочек. Но проседаний фпс не заметил, как говорится "у меня на компьютере все работает" :)

Comment: @MishaSaidov у тебя небось парочка 2080TI в режиме SLI и Core I9? (=

Comment: @iluxa1810 намек понял))) Думаю, это все от моего непрофессионализма. На канвасе было бы глаже (но я не шарю)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 у меня при проигрывании елочки одно ядро 2-ух ядерного процессора под 50% загружается и убивает производительность всего пк.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Бандл, который ниже сейчас, лучше не запускать)

Answer (score 34):

Начну для затравки.
Конкурс откроется сегодня, - **24.12.2018 г.** с хорошим вознаграждением.
 Как раз будем подводить итоги накануне Нового года.

Возьмусь, для примера, сделать первый пункт анимации из списка в вопросе. 
Так как я буду использовать в этой заготовке базовые команды svg и простые, общеизвестные приемы, то можно смело их использовать в конкурсных ответах, это не будет считаться копи-пастом.

> Лучи от звезды.

Я делаю в SVG, естественно возможно это реализовать и на `CSS`, `Javascript`, `jQuery`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">   
 
 <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%"
      fx="50%" fy="80%">
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:yellow;
      stop-opacity:1">
   <animate
   attributeName="offset"
   values="10%;90%;10%"
   dur="1.5s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </stop>
      <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:gold;
      stop-opacity:1.0"/>
    </radialGradient>  
    
     <radialGradient id="starGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="65%"
      fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:yellow;
      stop-opacity:1;">
   <animate
   attributeName="offset"
   values="10%;90%;10%"
   dur="2.5s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </stop>
      <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:crimson;
      stop-opacity:1;"/>
    </radialGradient>
   
 </defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#DBFF66"/>
 <path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.75" fill="url(#starGrad)" />
 
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.25" stroke="url(#radGrad)" stroke-dasharray="13.08 13.08" stroke-width="250" >
  <animate 
  attributeName="stroke-width"
  fill="yellow"
  fill-opacity="0.15"
  values="0;300;0"
  dur="8s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <!--  <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   values="0 200 200;180 200 200"
   dur="8s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
  </circle> 
 

</svg>
```

### Как это может быть сделано средствами SVG

- При радиусе `r="100"` длина окружности равна  `2 * 3,14 * 100 = 628px`
- Нужно получить 12 лучей + 12 промежутков = 24 равные части.  Одна
  часть равна `26,16px` 
  Подставляем длину черты и интервала в атрибут

  ```
  <circle stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
  ```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >   
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="yellowgreen"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

- Увеличиваем ширину строки до `stroke-width="200"`

Так как строка размещается симметрично по обе стороны от осевой линии окружности
 и при `r="100px"` её ширина должна быть `200px` для заполнения внутреннего пространства окружности.

Для демонстрации окружность заполнена цветом `fill="purple"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >   
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="purple"
    stroke="yellowgreen"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" />
</svg>
```

**Прототип снежинки**

Убираем заливку `fill="none"` и присваиваем `stroke="#87CEFA"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">   
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="#87CEFA"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" />
</svg>
```

- В центр лучей добавляем звёздочку

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  >  
<path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.75" fill="yellow" />
  
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="yellowgreen"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" />
</svg>
```

- Добавляем градиент лучей звезды и анимацию, к сожалению анимация в
  этом варианте работает только в `FF` Этот кусок кода закомментирован

  ```
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150%"
        fx="50%" fy="50%">
          <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:#D3B300; stop-opacity:1">
              <!--  <animate
                    attributeName="offset"
                    values="1%;90%;1%"
                    dur="2.5s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
          </stop>
          <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:yellow; stop-opacity:1.0"/>
      </radialGradient>  
  </defs>
  ```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  >  
 
 <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150%"
      fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:#D3B300;
      stop-opacity:1">
 <!--  <animate
   attributeName="offset"
   values="1%;90%;1%"
   dur="2.5s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
   </stop>
      <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:yellow;
      stop-opacity:1.0"/>
    </radialGradient>  
   </defs> 
 <path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="yellow" /> 
  
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="url(#radGrad)"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" /> 
</svg>
```

- Анимация вращения лучей звезды

  Для вращения объекта по часовой стрелке на один полный оборот необходимо добавить внутри его тегов команду анимации:

  ```
  <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        values="0 200 200;360 200 200"
        dur="2s"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  ```

Немного сложна семантика тегов объекта при использовании вложенной анимации.

Внести ясность поможет топик: [Эти странные теги SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792782/28748)

*Ниже код анимации вращения лучей звезды*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
 
 <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150%"
      fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:gold;
      stop-opacity:1">
 <!--  <animate
   attributeName="offset"
   values="1%;90%;1%"
   dur="2.5s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
   </stop>
      <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:yellow;
      stop-opacity:1.0"/>
    </radialGradient>  
   </defs> 
 <path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="dodgerblue" /> 
  
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="url(#radGrad)"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" >
     <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       values="0 200 200;360 200 200"
       dur="2s"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>  
</svg>
```

- Усложняем алгоритм вращения

  ```
  values="0 200 200;720 200 200;720 200 200;0 200 200;0 200 200"
  ```

  Поворот по часовой стрелке на 720 °   → пауза   → поворот против часовой стрелки на 720 ° → пауза

  ```html
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
   
   <defs>
      <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150%"
        fx="50%" fy="50%">
        <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:gold;
        stop-opacity:1">
   <!--  <animate
     attributeName="offset"
     values="1%;90%;1%"
     dur="2.5s"
     repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
     </stop>
        <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:yellow;
        stop-opacity:1.0"/>
      </radialGradient>  
     </defs> 
   <path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.5" fill="dodgerblue" /> 
    
      <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
      fill="none"
      stroke="url(#radGrad)"
      stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
      stroke-width="200" >
       <animateTransform
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         values="0 200 200;720 200 200;720 200 200;0 200 200;0 200 200"
         dur="8s"
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>  
  </svg>
  ```
- Подбирая углы, их порядок следования, а также изменяя время вращения
  `dur="3.43s"`, можно получить интересные эффекты

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  >  
 
 <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radGrad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150%"
      fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:gold;
      stop-opacity:1">
 <!--  <animate
   attributeName="offset"
   values="1%;90%;1%"
   dur="2.5s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/> -->
   </stop>
      <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color:yellow;
      stop-opacity:1.0"/>
    </radialGradient>  
   </defs> 
 <path transform="translate(100 105)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="1" fill="dodgerblue" /> 
  
     <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100"
    fill="none"
    stroke="url(#radGrad)"
    stroke-dasharray="26.16 26.16"
    stroke-width="200" >
     <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       values="0 200 200;1440 200 200;720 200 200;0 200 200"
       dur="3.43s"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 28):

Думаю, можно поменьше js при желании, а так вроде норм, красиво)

**Снежинки**

```js
let params = {
  amount: 30,
  duration: {
    min: 2,
    max: 6
  }, //s
  size: {
    min: 10,
    max: 20
  }
}

const randomBetween = (a, b) => {
  return (a + (Math.random() * (b - a)));
}
const randomArr = (arr) => {
  return arr[Math.round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1))];
}

const snowflakes = [
  "http://pngimg.com/uploads/snowflakes/snowflakes_PNG7578.png",
  "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/2/27/Snowflake.png/revision/latest?cb=20121220012520",
  "https://latxikadelacerveza.es/wp-content/plugins/christmas-panda/assets/images/snowflake_5.png"
];

$(document).ready(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < params.amount; i++) {
    let snowflake = $("<img class='snowflake' src='" + randomArr(snowflakes) + "'>");
    let randomSize = randomBetween(params.size.min, params.size.max);
    snowflake.css({
      "width": randomSize + "px",
      "height": randomSize + "px",
      "left": randomBetween(0, 100) + "%",
      "animation-duration": randomBetween(params.duration.min, params.duration.max) + "s"
    });

    $("#root").append(snowflake);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.snowflake {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: drop;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: Стыдно признавать, но да

Comment: @Alexandr_TT фигасе! Ёлку только выставили, и тут же почти нарядили))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну разве что гирлянды помогу развесить) Может игрушки ещё. Попрактикую CSS )) Было бы на что вешать))

Comment: Если не усну, поломаю голову над елочкой )

Answer (score 21):

### Варианты  анимации фразы - С Новым 2019 годом!

Этот вариант не участвует в конкурсе, создан для примера. Участники могут брать эту технику анимации прорисовки и раскрашивания букв в качестве заготовки и использовать, творчески переработав, в своих конкурсных ответах.

[Как сделать анимацию обводки букв](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919561/28748)  - подробно, с картинками рассказывается как это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*update  Новый вариант*

```css
<style>
  width:100%;
  heighr:100;
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1318 1054" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
   <defs>
     <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
   </defs> 
 <image height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgAH7.jpg"/>
 <g fill="transparent" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(0 100)" filter="url(#shadow)">
 
  <path id="L1" transform="translate(-280 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="gold"  stroke-dasharray="327" stroke-dashoffset="327" d="m248.8 131.1 2.9-6h2.6l1.1 24.8h-2.8q-2.7-10.5-6.9-15.4-5.2-6.2-12.3-6.2-7.7 0-12.6 6.9-4.9 6.9-4.9 23.4 0 13.9 5.6 21.2 4.8 6.2 13.3 6.2 7.5 0 12.6-4.8 5.1-4.8 6.6-14.5h3q-1.3 11-7.5 16.9-6.2 5.9-15.7 5.9-7.7 0-14.2-3.9-6.4-3.9-10.3-11.1-3.8-7.3-3.8-16 0-9.2 4-17.3 4-8.1 10.2-12.1 6.2-4.1 13.4-4.1 4 0 7.8 1.4 3.8 1.4 8.2 4.7zM288.6 126.3">
     <animate id="an_L1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="0.8s"  values="327;0" fill="freeze" />
  <animate id="fill_L1" attributeName="fill" begin="an_L16.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;yellow" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
  
  <path id="L2" transform="translate(-290 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="crimson"  stroke-dasharray="458" stroke-dashoffset="458" d="m288.6 126.3h26.3v3.1h-4.8q-2.5 0-3.3 0.9-0.7 0.9-0.7 4.3v19h28.2v-19q0-3.6-0.7-4.4-0.7-0.8-3.4-0.8h-4.5v-3.1h26.2v3.1h-4.8q-1.8 0-2.5 0.5-0.7 0.5-1.2 1.6-0.2 0.7-0.2 3.7v44.3q0 3.2 0.5 3.9 1.1 1.4 4 1.4h4.3v3.1h-26.2v-3.1h4.5q2.7 0 3.6-1.5 0.5-0.8 0.5-4.2v-21.4h-28.2v21.8q0 3.3 0.5 3.9 1 1.4 3.6 1.4h4.8v3.1h-26.3v-3.1h5q1.3 0 2.1-0.5 0.8-0.5 1.2-1.5 0.2-0.7 0.2-3.5v-44.5q0-3.5-0.8-4.3-0.7-0.9-3.3-0.9h-4.4z"> 
   <animate id="an_L2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L1.end" dur="0.8s"  values="458;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L2" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L1.end" dur="0.3s"  values="transparent;red" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
  <g id="new" transform="translate(-75)">
 <path id="L3" stroke="yellowgreen"  stroke-dasharray="346" stroke-dashoffset="346" d="m388.4 125q7.8 0 14.6 4.1 6.8 4.1 10.7 11.5 3.9 7.3 3.9 16.5 0 9.2-3.9 16.6-3.9 7.4-10.7 11.6-6.7 4.1-14.3 4.1-7.4 0-13.9-4-6.5-4.1-10.5-11.6-3.9-7.6-3.9-16.8 0-9.1 3.8-16.4 3.8-7.3 10.5-11.5 6.6-4.2 13.8-4.2zm0.7 3.2q-8.1 0-13.2 6.8-5 6.8-5 22 0 16.5 5.2 22.9 5.2 6.3 12.8 6.3 5.3 0 9.4-2.9 4-2.9 6.4-9.1 2.4-6.2 2.4-16.4 0-11.1-2.2-17.3-2.2-6.2-6.4-9.2-4.2-3-9.3-3z"> 
   <animate id="an_L3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L2.end" dur="0.5s"  values="346;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L3" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L2.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;greenyellow" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
   <path id="L4" stroke="#00C4FF"  stroke-dasharray="430" stroke-dashoffset="430" d="m426.1 126.3h32.1q9.5 0 14.5 4.2 5 4.2 5 10.5 0 5.3-3.5 8.9-3.5 3.7-10.5 5.8 8.7 1.8 13 5.8 4.4 3.9 4.4 9.9 0 4.6-2.5 8.1-2.5 3.5-8.2 6-5.7 2.5-13.1 2.5h-31.2v-3.1h5.1q2.3 0 3.3-0.7 1.1-0.7 1.1-1.7v-49.4q0-1.7-1-2.6-1-0.9-3-0.9h-5.4zm18.4 28.3h11.7q5.4 0 8.5-3.2 3.2-3.2 3.2-10.4 0-4.5-1.5-7-1.5-2.5-4.4-3.6-2.9-1.2-10-1.2-5 0-6.2 0.8-1.2 0.7-1.2 2.5zm0 3.1v23.8q0 1.7 1 2.5 1 0.8 3.5 0.8h7.5q7.4 0 11-3.2 3.5-3.3 3.5-10.2 0-6.3-3.7-10-3.7-3.7-10.1-3.7z"> 
   <animate id="an_L4" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L3.end" dur="0.5s"  values="430;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L4" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L3.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;cyan" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
      <path id="L5" stroke="#ED00FF"  stroke-dasharray="557" stroke-dashoffset="557" d="m487.8 187.9v-3.1h3.4q2.7 0 3.7-0.5 1-0.6 1.2-1.4 0.3-0.8 0.3-3.3v-46.1q0-2.4-0.7-3.2-0.7-0.8-2.8-0.8h-5v-3.1h28.4v3.1h-7q-2.4 0-3.2 1.1-0.7 1.1-0.7 3.5v19.1h12.5q10.4 0 16.3 4.6 5.9 4.5 5.9 13 0 7.6-5.3 12.4-5.3 4.8-15.9 4.8zm17.4-31.6v23.9q0 2.5 0.9 3.6 0.9 1 3.7 1h5.3q9.5 0 12.4-3.6 2.9-3.6 2.9-10.5 0-7.5-3.6-10.9-3.5-3.5-11.5-3.5zm35.6-30h28.4v3.1h-4.9q-3.2 0-4.1 0.8-0.8 0.8-0.8 3.4v46.7q0 2.8 0.8 3.5 1 1 3.6 1h5.5v3.1h-28.4v-3.1h5.4q2.8 0 3.7-0.8 0.8-0.8 0.8-3.6v-46.7q0-2.7-0.7-3.3-1.2-1-4.3-1h-4.8z"> 
   <animate id="an_L5" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L4.end" dur="0.5s"  values="557;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L5" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L4.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;magenta" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
       <path id="L6" stroke="yellow"  stroke-dasharray="810" stroke-dashoffset="810" d="m573.3 126.3h20.5l18.4 48.7 17-48.7h21v3.1h-5.1q-2.7 0-3.7 0.8-0.9 0.8-0.9 2.8v48.8q0 1.5 1.1 2.3 1.1 0.8 3.9 0.8h4.7v3.1h-28.2v-3.1h5.3q2.3 0 3.3-0.8 1.1-0.9 1.1-2.2v-52.3l-20.4 58.5h-2.8l-21.9-58.3v44.8q0 4 1 6 1 2 2.8 3 1.9 1 6.2 1.3v3.1h-23.2v-3.1q5.7-0.4 7.8-2.5 2-2.1 2-7.4v-42.5q0-1.6-1-2.3-1-0.7-3.6-0.7h-5.2z"> 
   <animate id="an_L6" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L5.end" dur="0.5s"  values="810;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L6" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L5.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;gold" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
      <path id="L7" transform="translate(-420 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="crimson"  stroke-dasharray="810" stroke-dashoffset="810" d="m689.5 178.8q-1.9 2.5 18.9 2.5 3.1 0 4.5-1.6 1.3-1.6 3-9h2.8l-1.3 17.3h-37.3v-2.2l12.1-13.8q10.1-11 12.2-13.8 2.9-4 4.3-7.8 1.3-3.8 1.3-6.9 0-5.1-2.8-8-2.8-3-7.9-3-5.7 0-9.2 2.7-3.6 2.7-3.6 5.8 0 1 0.5 1.6 0.5 0.5 2.2 1 4.2 1 4.2 4.9 0 2.1-1.4 3.5-1.4 1.4-3.6 1.4-2.5 0-4.5-2.3-1.9-2.4-1.9-6.2 0-4.2 2.2-7.7 2.2-3.5 6.6-5.7 4.4-2.3 9.5-2.3 5 0 9.3 2.2 4.3 2.2 6.5 5.7 2.2 3.5 2.2 7.7 0 2.9-1.1 5.8-1.1 3-3.2 5.5-3.6 4.5-7.4 7.6l-11 9.3q-4.2 3.5-6.1 6z"> 
   <animate id="an_L7" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L6.end" dur="0.5s"  values="810;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L7" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L6.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;red" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
      
     <path id="L8" transform="translate(-420 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="crimson"  stroke-dasharray="292" stroke-dashoffset="292" d="m747.4 129.1q8.1 0 13.5 6.3 6.7 7.8 6.7 23.6 0 14.7-5.8 22.4-5.8 7.7-14.1 7.7-8 0-13.3-6.5-6.7-8.1-6.7-23.5 0-14.6 6.3-23.2 5-6.9 13.3-6.9zm0.3 3q-5.5 0-8.6 5.3-3.1 5.3-3.1 21.8 0 16.2 3.2 21.6 3.2 5.4 8.6 5.4 5.4 0 8.3-5 3.5-6 3.5-21.7 0-16.3-3.2-21.9-3.2-5.5-8.6-5.5z"> 
   <animate id="an_L8" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L7.end" dur="0.5s"  values="292;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L8" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L7.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;red" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
        <path id="L9" transform="translate(-420 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="crimson"  stroke-dasharray="192" stroke-dashoffset="192" d="m800.1 130.1v52q0 1.2 0.8 1.8 1.2 0.9 3 0.9h8.1v3.1h-30v-3.1h6.9q2.2 0 3.2-1 1-1 1-2.7v-39.3q0-1.2-1-2-1-0.8-2.5-0.8h-9.2v-2.9q6.5-0.8 10.5-2.2 4-1.4 7.1-3.7z"> 
   <animate id="an_L9" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L8.end" dur="0.5s"  values="192;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L9" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L8.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;red" fill="freeze" />
 </path>   
 
     <path id="L10" transform="translate(-420 -110) scale(1.6)" stroke="crimson"  stroke-dasharray="325" stroke-dashoffset="325" d="m854.4 158q-2.7 4.1-6.3 6.2-3.6 2-8.1 2-6.2 0-11.4-4.4-5.1-4.4-5.1-12.9 0-8.3 5.6-14.1 5.7-5.8 13.5-5.8 8.6 0 14.4 7.2 5.8 7.2 5.8 20.1 0 10.8-3.2 18.2-3.2 7.4-8.4 11-5.2 3.6-11.8 3.6-6.4 0-10-2.8-3.6-2.8-3.6-6.7 0-2.6 1.5-4.2 1.5-1.6 3.8-1.6 2 0 3.5 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 3.3 0 1.4-1.3 3-0.8 1-0.8 1.8 0 1.2 1.4 2 1.4 0.8 4.4 0.8 4.3 0 7.6-2.4 3.3-2.4 5.3-7.9 2-5.5 2-14.2zm-11.7-26q-4.7 0-7.7 3.9-3 3.9-3 11.7 0 7.2 3 10.7 3 3.5 7.8 3.5 4.8 0 8-3.8 3.3-3.8 3.3-10.6 0-7.1-3.4-11.2-3.4-4.2-8.1-4.2z"> 
   <animate id="an_L10" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L9.end" dur="0.5s"  values="325;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L10" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L9.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;red" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
 
     <path id="L11" transform="translate(90 0) " stroke="yellowgreen"  stroke-dasharray="279" stroke-dashoffset="279" d="m893.8 126.3h47.6l0.8 21.2h-2.9q-2-11.8-6.1-15-4.2-3.1-10.5-3.1h-8.7q-2.7 0-2.7 2.8v48.8q0 2.2 1 3 1 0.8 3.4 0.8h6.4v3.1h-28.2v-3.1h5q3.5 0 3.5-3.3v-49q0-3.1-3.8-3.1h-4.7z"> 
   <animate id="an_L11" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L10.end" dur="0.5s"  values="279;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L11" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L10.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;greenyellow" fill="freeze" />
 </path>    
 
     <path id="L12" transform="translate(90 0)" stroke="#00C4FF"  stroke-dasharray="346" stroke-dashoffset="346" d="m975.4 125q7.8 0 14.6 4.1 6.8 4.1 10.7 11.5 3.9 7.3 3.9 16.5 0 9.2-3.9 16.6-3.9 7.4-10.7 11.6-6.7 4.1-14.3 4.1-7.4 0-13.9-4-6.5-4.1-10.5-11.6-3.9-7.6-3.9-16.8 0-9.1 3.8-16.4 3.8-7.3 10.5-11.5 6.6-4.2 13.8-4.2zm0.7 3.2q-8.1 0-13.2 6.8-5 6.8-5 22 0 16.5 5.2 22.9 5.2 6.3 12.8 6.3 5.3 0 9.4-2.9 4-2.9 6.4-9.1 2.4-6.2 2.4-16.4 0-11.1-2.2-17.3-2.2-6.2-6.4-9.2-4.2-3-9.3-3z"> 
   <animate id="an_L12" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L11.end" dur="0.5s"  values="346;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L12" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L11.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;cyan" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
    
  
     <path id="L13" transform="translate(90 0) " stroke="#ED00FF"  stroke-dasharray="485" stroke-dashoffset="485" d="m1072.8 184.8v18.5h-3.1q-0.4-4.7-1.7-8.2-1.4-3.4-6-5.3-4.5-1.9-9.2-1.9h-24.5q-6.9 0-11.4 3.1-4.5 3.2-4.7 12h-3.1l0.6-18.6q5.3-0.2 8.4-1.9 3.1-1.7 6.4-7.8 3.3-6.1 4.5-14.4 1.2-8.3 1.2-19.3 0-6.7-2-9.3-2-2.6-6-2.6h-0.9v-2.8h51.4v3.1h-4.6q-2.4 0-3.2 1-0.8 1-0.8 4.8v44.3q0 5.3 4.9 5.3zm-17.3-0.3v-55.1h-10.6q-5.1 0-7.1 1.5-2 1.4-2.5 4.2-0.5 2.7-0.9 11.5-0.7 18.2-5 27-4.2 8.8-9.9 11z"> 
   <animate id="an_L13" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L12.end" dur="0.5s"  values="485;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L13" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L12.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;magenta" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
       <path id="L14" transform="translate(90 0) " stroke="yellow"  stroke-dasharray="348" stroke-dashoffset="348" d="m1109.4 125q7.8 0 14.6 4.1 6.8 4.1 10.7 11.5 3.9 7.3 3.9 16.5 0 9.2-3.9 16.6-3.9 7.4-10.7 11.6-6.7 4.1-14.3 4.1-7.4 0-13.9-4-6.5-4.1-10.5-11.6-3.9-7.6-3.9-16.8 0-9.1 3.8-16.4 3.8-7.3 10.5-11.5 6.6-4.2 13.8-4.2zm0.7 3.2q-8.1 0-13.2 6.8-5 6.8-5 22 0 16.5 5.2 22.9 5.2 6.3 12.8 6.3 5.3 0 9.4-2.9 4-2.9 6.4-9.1 2.4-6.2 2.4-16.4 0-11.1-2.2-17.3-2.2-6.2-6.4-9.2-4.2-3-9.3-3z"> 
   <animate id="an_L14" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L13.end" dur="0.5s"  values="348;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L14" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L13.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;gold" fill="freeze" />
 </path>   
       <path id="L15" transform="translate(90 0) " stroke="yellowgreen"  stroke-dasharray="610" stroke-dashoffset="610" d="m1144.5 126.3h20.5l18.4 48.7 17-48.7h21v3.1h-5.1q-2.7 0-3.7 0.8-0.9 0.8-0.9 2.8v48.8q0 1.5 1.1 2.3 1.1 0.8 3.9 0.8h4.7v3.1h-28.2v-3.1h5.3q2.3 0 3.3-0.8 1.1-0.9 1.1-2.2v-52.3l-20.4 58.5h-2.8l-21.9-58.3v44.8q0 4 1 6 1 2 2.8 3 1.9 1 6.2 1.3v3.1h-23.2v-3.1q5.7-0.4 7.8-2.5 2-2.1 2-7.4v-42.5q0-1.6-1-2.3-1-0.7-3.6-0.7h-5.2z"> 
   <animate id="an_L15" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L14.end" dur="0.5s"  values="610;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L15" attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L14.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;greenyellow" fill="freeze" />
 </path>  
       <path id="L16" transform="translate(-510 -93) scale(1.5)" stroke="red"  stroke-dasharray="131" stroke-dashoffset="131" d="m1237.5 169.9h-2.2q0-7.5-0.4-11.2-0.6-6.1-2.1-14.5-1.6-9.3-1.6-12.2 0-3.6 1.5-5.4 1.5-1.8 3.8-1.8 2.5 0 3.9 1.8 1.4 1.7 1.4 5.4 0 3.1-1.7 12.3-1.5 8.1-2 13.4-0.5 5.3-0.6 12.2zm-1 9.1q2.1 0 3.6 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 3.6 0 2-1.5 3.5-1.5 1.5-3.6 1.5-2.1 0-3.6-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5-3.6 0-2.2 1.5-3.6 1.5-1.5 3.6-1.5z"> 
   <animate id="an_L16" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_L15.end" dur="0.5s"  values="131;0" fill="freeze" />
   <animate id="fill_L16"   attributeName="fill" begin="fill_L5.end" dur="0.4s"  values="transparent;crimson" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
 </g>
 </g>
 </svg>
 </div>
```

### #2 Анимация  волной

Подробно теория и примеры, как это сделать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647589/28748)

```css
svg {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNCaY.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width:50%
  height:50%
  }
 </style>
```

```html
 <svg   viewBox="0 0 650 500">
 
<defs> 
 <path id="Lsvg" d="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200" style="stroke:teal;fill-opacity:0.3;stroke-width:3;fill:none;filter:url(#shadow);">
<animate begin="0.5s"
dur="10s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
restart="whenNotActive"
attributeName="d" 
values="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,300 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200"/> 
</path>
<filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
</defs>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="36" fill="crimson" filter="url(#shadow)">
  <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#Lsvg"><tspan dy="-20">С Новым 2019 годом!</tspan></textPath>
<animate
 begin="0s"
 dur="10s"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 attributeName="fill"
 values="purple;yellowgreen;yellow;red;cyan;purple"/>
</text>
<use xlink:href="#Lsvg" transform="translate(0 -10)"/>
   
  <rect id="animLink" x="100" y="150" width="400" height="60" fill="#E0E0E0" fill-opacity="0.01" stroke="none" />  

 </svg>
```

### #3 Двойная анимация,- волны и букв на ней

```css
svg {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ENnq.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width:50%
  height:50%
  }
```

```html
 <svg   viewBox="0 0 650 500">
 
<defs> 
 <path transform="translate(-30 100)" id="Lsvg" d="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200" style="fill:none; stroke:cyan;stroke-opacity:0.4;stroke-width:5;filter:url(#shadow);">
<!-- Анимация кривой линии (кривой Безье) -->
 <animate begin="0.5s"
dur="10s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
restart="whenNotActive"
attributeName="d" 
values="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,300 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200"/> 
<!-- Анимация изменения цвета строки--> 
<animate
 begin="0s"
 dur="14s"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 attributeName="stroke"
 values="purple;yellowgreen;yellow;#D05589;#D05589;cyan;purple"/>
</path>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
    


</defs>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="42" fill="purple" filter="url(#shadow)" >
  <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="-48%" xlink:href="#Lsvg"><tspan dx="0" dy="-20">С Новым 2019 годом!</tspan>
 <!-- Движение фразы вдоль кривой линии -->  
  <animate
   dur="15s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="150%;50%;50%;50%;50%;50%;50%;50%;-50%"/> 
</textPath>
 
<!-- Анимация изменения цвета --> 
<animate
 begin="0s"
 dur="14s"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 attributeName="fill"
 values="purple;yellowgreen;yellow;#D05589;#D05589;cyan;purple"/>
</text>
<use xlink:href="#Lsvg" transform="translate(0 -10)"/>
   
  <rect id="animLink" x="100" y="150" width="400" height="60" fill="#E0E0E0" fill-opacity="0.01" stroke="none" />  

 </svg>
```

Comment: а можно анимацию чуть шире сделать? И чтобы буквы не исчезали, а ходили "гусеничкой", примерно как у меня здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/914395/265406 ?

Comment: @UModeL буквы гусеничкой видел раньше, понравилось тогда, нравится и сейчас :) Что ты предложил, сделать вполне на svg возможно. Может и сделаю со временем, но сейчас есть другие идеи, которые хочется реализовать

Answer (score 20):

### Дед Мороз и ёлка

*Это внеконкурсный ответ*

Только HTML и CSS.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 105);
}

.wrap_hy {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 615px;
  height: 615px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.yolka {
  --size: 160px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(var(--size) * 2.647);
  height: calc(var(--size) * 1);
  font-size: 0;
}

.zvezda {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0% 50%;
  color: #fc2e5a;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #fc2e5a;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: translate(-51%, 15%) scale(-0.4, 0.4) rotate(35deg);
}

.zvezda:before {
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  border-bottom: 80px solid #fc2e5a;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}

.zvezda:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  color: #fc2e5a;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}

ul {
  --luchi-flash: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  left: 50%;
  top: 28%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  list-style: none;
  animation: luchi_rotate 10s infinite linear;
}

li,
li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-width: 1.2em 20em;
  border-color: transparent rgba(255, 193, 7, var(--luchi-flash));
  animation: luchi_flash 4s infinite 0s ease;
}

li {
  left: -20em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  transform: rotate(0.1deg);
}

li:before,
li:after {
  content: "";
  left: -20em;
  top: -1.2em;
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

li:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(2):before,
li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-color: transparent rgba(244, 94, 4, var(--luchi-flash));
  animation: luchi_flash 4s infinite 1s ease;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

li:nth-child(3),
li:nth-child(3):before,
li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-color: transparent rgba(147, 251, 25, var(--luchi-flash));
  animation: luchi_flash 4s infinite 2s ease;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(4):before,
li:nth-child(4):after {
  border-color: transparent rgba(156, 39, 176, var(--luchi-flash));
  animation: luchi_flash 4s infinite 2s ease;
}

@keyframes luchi_rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes luchi_flash {
  0%,
  100% {
    --luchi-flash: 0.2;
  }
  50% {
    --luchi-flash: 0.5;
  }
}

.yarus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
}

.yarus:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 40%);
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
}

.yarus:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: -2;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 80%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}

.yarus:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: -3;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 160%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.yarus div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0% 100% / 0 0 0% 66%;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle closest-corner at 34% -68%, transparent 117%, #fbfbfb 122%, #808080 140%, #015001 141%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 calc(var(--size) * -0.3) calc(var(--size) * 0.2) calc(var(--size) * -0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.yarus div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.stvol {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 330%) perspective(200px) rotateX(45deg);
  height: 70%;
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 15%;
  background: #795548;
  box-shadow: inset 0 calc(var(--size) * -0.1) calc(var(--size) * 0.3) calc(var(--size) * -0.1) white, inset 0 calc(var(--size) * 0.34) calc(var(--size) * 0.4) black;
}

.girlyanda div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-43%, 56%) rotate(19deg);
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 95% 95%;
  border: 12px dotted;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px -25px;
  animation: girlyanda 2.1s ease-in infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.girlyanda div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 95% 95%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-top: none;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-42%, 119%) rotate(19deg);
  height: 56%;
  width: 69%;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-48%, 176%) rotate(23deg);
  height: 80%;
  width: 84%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(-42%, 125%) rotate(-51deg);
  height: 35%;
  width: 44%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate(-38%, 291%) rotate(-51deg);
  height: 35%;
  width: 68%;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate(-54%, 283%) rotate(18deg);
  height: 45%;
  width: 67%;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.girlyanda div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translate(-71%, 304%) rotate(-7deg);
  height: 59%;
  width: 55%;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes girlyanda {
  0%,
  100% {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    color: rgba(255, 210, 0, 1);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgb(0, 199, 0);
  }
  75% {
    color: rgb(46, 137, 255);
  }
}

.ded_moroz {
  position: relative;
}

.shapka {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 75px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px / 70px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 13px -3px black;
}

.shapka:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 75px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 105px / 53px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 13px -3px black;
}

.boroda_lico {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 130px;
  width: 110px;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 60px 60px / 55px 55px 85px 85px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 13px -3px black;
}

.boroda_lico:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50px / 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 214, 195, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px -3px black;
}

.glaz_l {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 60px 60px / 55px 55px 85px 85px;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px white;
  animation: morganie 5s infinite linear, oglyad_glaza 15s infinite linear;
}

.glaz_r {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 60px 60px / 55px 55px 85px 85px;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px white;
  animation: morganie 5s infinite linear, oglyad_glaza 15s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes morganie {
  0%,
  10%,
  15%,
  100% {
    height: 15px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  11% {
    height: 3px;
    top: 25px;
  }
}

@keyframes oglyad_glaza {
  0%,
  10%,
  24%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  12%,
  14% {
    transform: translateX(-30%);
  }
  19%,
  21% {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
}

.nos_brovi {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 26px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 168, 168);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 13px -3px black, 0px 2px 10px -3px black;
}

.nos_brovi:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-25deg);
  height: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 0px 80px / 50px 50px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 6px -3px black, 0px 2px 10px -3px black;
  animation: oglyad_brovi_l 15s infinite linear;
}

.nos_brovi:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: -45%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(25deg);
  height: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 80px 0px / 50px 50px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 6px -3px black, 0px 2px 10px -3px black;
  animation: oglyad_brovi_r 15s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes oglyad_brovi_l {
  0%,
  10%,
  19%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-25deg);
  }
  13%,
  16% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes oglyad_brovi_r {
  0%,
  17%,
  25%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(25deg);
  }
  20%,
  22% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.rot_usw {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 26px;
  width: 53px;
}

.rot_usw:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: -5%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-40deg);
  height: 32px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 80px / 50px 50px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 6px -3px black, 0px 2px 10px -3px black;
}

.rot_usw:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: -105%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(40deg);
  height: 32px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 80px 0px / 50px 50px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 6px -3px black, 0px 2px 10px -3px black;
}

.tulup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 355px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 40% 40% 10% 10%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset -13px 0px 73px -3px black;
}

.tulup:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 35px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 20% 20% 40% 40%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset -23px 0px 53px -15px black;
}

.tulup:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 350px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 20% 20% 40% 40%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: 1px -10px 16px -5px black;
}

.plecho_l {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 100% 60% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.plecho_r {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 60% 100% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset -15px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.lokot_l {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100% 60% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.lokot_l:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 35%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.lokot_r {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 60% 100% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset -15px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.lokot_r:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 35%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.kist_l {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 5px;
  right: -30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 100% 60% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 214, 195, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}

.kist_r {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 60% 100% 55px 55px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 214, 195, 1);
  box-shadow: inset -15px -10px 53px -15px black, 1px 10px 16px -5px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_hy">
  <div class="yolka">
    <div class="zvezda">
      <div class="zvezda">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yarus">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yarus">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yarus">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yarus">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stvol">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="girlyanda">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="luchi">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="ded_moroz">
    <div class="telo">
      <div class="tulup">
        <div class="plecho_l">
          <div class="lokot_l">
            <div class="kist_l">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="plecho_r">
          <div class="lokot_r">
            <div class="kist_r">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="golova">
      <div class="shapka"></div>
      <div class="boroda_lico">
        <div class="glaz_l"></div>
        <div class="glaz_r"></div>
        <div class="rot_usw"></div>
        <div class="nos_brovi"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дед мороз грустноватый :D А так ничего, мне понравилось.

Comment: @LLENN некогда было веселить деда - до обеда на работе был))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT потому, что это "поделка-недоделка" ;-) Ну, не было времени, а задумка там была большая.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я постепенно "допилю" до конца, но пока, вне конкурса.

Comment: Классно, оооочень нравится!!! Дедушка грустноватый видимо потому что без снегурочки :))))

Answer (score 18):

Начну делать елку с звезды. Я сделал лучи заднего плана полностью на линейных градиентах без svg. Звезду позаимстовал у SE и добавил эффект свечения. Получилось вот что-то такое:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#star_back {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#star_back:after, #star_back:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, black 50%, black), linear-gradient(82deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(67deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(52deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(37deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(22deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(7deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(-8deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(-23deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(-38deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(-53deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(-68deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), linear-gradient(-83deg, transparent 50%, green 50%, green), linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 50%, lightgreen 50%, lightgreen), radial-gradient(transparent 90%, white 10%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;

}
#star_back:before {
  left: 120px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#star_gradient{
  background: radial-gradient(transparent, lightgreen);
    width: 240px;
    height: 220px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
#star{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px gold ); 
        filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 10px gold );
}
```

```html
<div id="star_back"><div id = "star_gradient"><svg aria-hidden="true" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" id = "star"><path d="M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z" fill="gold"></path></svg></div></div>
```

Comment: Нужен Первый плюс ))

Answer (score 18):

d3.js  интерактивная версия

> никаких внешних ресурсов не использовано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**updates 06.01.2019:**

- можно перетащить игрушки на елку, чтобы они замигали
- теперь падает снег и есть сугробы
- добавлены фильтры для придания плавных переходов между фигугами и для придания псевдо объема игрушкам

**updates 08.01.2019:**

- появляется текст

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="margin: 0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .text-effect {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        width: 620px;
        margin-left: calc(50vw - 310px);
        top: calc(50vh - 300px);
        -webkit-filter: contrast(110%) brightness(190%);
        filter: contrast(110%) brightness(190%);
    }
    .neon {
        position: relative;
        background: black;
        color: transparent;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .neon::before, .neon::after {
        content: attr(data-text);
        color: white;
        -webkit-filter: blur(0.02em);
        filter: blur(0.02em);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .neon::after {
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }
    .gradient, .spotlight {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .gradient {
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f9ff09, #ff00f9);
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    }
    .spotlight {
        -webkit-animation: light 5s infinite linear;
        animation: light 5s infinite linear;
        background: radial-gradient(circle, white, transparent 25%) 0 0/25% 25%,
                    radial-gradient(circle, white, black 25%) 50% 50%/12.5% 12.5%;
        top: -100%;
        left: -100%;
        mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes light {
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes light {
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
        }
    }
    .neon {
        font: 700 220px sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .neon:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="text-effect" style="display: none; position: fixed; mix-blend-mode: lighten;">
    <h1 class="neon" data-text="20&nbsp;&nbsp;19" contenteditable>20&nbsp;&nbsp;19</h1>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="spotlight"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var w = 800, h = 600;
    var c = [w / 2, h / 2 + 100];
    var svg = appendSvg();
    var defs = svg.append('defs');

    filter_smoothMin('smin');
    filter_3d('3d');

    hills();
    tree();
    toys();
    snow();

    function snow() {
        var snowFlakes = svg.append('g')
            .style('filter', 'url(#smin)')
            .selectAll('.snowflake')
            .data(d3.range(100).map(function () {
                return Math.random() * h
            }))
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .classed('.snowflake', true)
            .attr('fill', 'snow')
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .each(function (d) {
                animate(d3.select(this), (1000 + Math.random() * 2000) * (h - d) / h)
            });

        setInterval(loopAnimation, 100);

        function loopAnimation() {
            snowFlakes.filter(function () {
                var y = +d3.select(this).attr('cy');
                return y >= 600 || !y;
            }).attr('cy', -30).each(function () {
                animate(d3.select(this), 1000 + Math.random() * 2000);
            })
        }

        function animate(selection, t) {
            selection
                .attr('cx', function (d) {
                    return Math.random() * w;
                })
                .attr('r', function () {
                    return 3 + Math.random() * 3;
                })
                .transition()
                .duration(t)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .attr('cx', function (d) {
                    return +selection.attr('cx') +
                        Math.random() * 100 * Math.sign(Math.random() - 0.5);
                })
                .attr('cy', h);
        }
    }

    function hills() {
        svg.append('g')
            .style('filter', 'url(#smin)')
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(d3.range(0, 10).map(function (i) {
                return 1500 - i * 100 + h / 2;
            }))
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('cx', function (d) {
                return w * 2 * Math.random() - w;
            })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
                return d + h / 2;
            })
            .attr('r', function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr('fill', '#f2f2f2')
            .attr('stroke-width', '1')
            .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
    }

    function tree() {

        bark();
        level(0);
        level(1);
        level(2);

        function bark() {
            svg.append('path')
                .attr('d', m(20, 40) + l(20, 70) + l(0, 80) + l(0, 50))
                .attr('fill', '#5B3413');

            svg.append('path')
                .attr('d', m(-20, 40) + l(-20, 70) + l(0, 80) + l(0, 50))
                .attr('fill', 'brown');
        }

        function level(i) {
            var s = 100 - i * 20;
            var g = svg.append('g')
                .style('filter', 'url(#smin)');

            path(m(0, s / 2) + l(-s, 0) + l(0, -s * 2))
                .attr('fill', 'lightgreen');

            path(m(0, s / 2) + l(s, 0) + l(0, -s * 2))
                .attr('fill', 'green');

            path(m(s, 0) + l(0, s / 2) + l(-s, 0)).attr('stroke', 'white')
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
                .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
                .attr('stroke-width', '12');

            function path(d) {
                return g.append('path')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0 ' + (-i * 100) + ') ')
                    .attr('d', d);
            }
        }
    }

    function toys() {
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        var toys = d3.range(0, 9).map(function (i) {
            return {
                x: 50 + Math.random() * (w - 100),
                y: h - 125 + Math.random() * 100,
                shape: i % d3.symbols.length,
                color: color(Math.random() * 10),
                angle: Math.random() * 360
            }
        });

        var symbols = svg.append('g')
            .classed('toys', true)
            .style('filter', 'url(#3d)')
            .selectAll('.symbol')
            .data(toys)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .classed('symbol', true)
            .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', translate)
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .attr('stroke-width', '0')
            .attr('fill', "gray")
            .attr('d', d3.symbol().size(function () {
                return 512 + Math.random() * 512;
            }).type(function (d, i) {
                return d3.symbols[i % d3.symbols.length];
            }))
            .each(dragged)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));

        function dragstarted(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .classed('active', true)
                .raise()
                .attr("transform", translate)
                .attr("stroke-width", 2);

        }

        function dragged(d) {
            if (d3.event) {
                d.x = d3.event.x;
                d.y = d3.event.y;
            }
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("transform", translate)
                .attr("fill", check(d) ? d.color : "gray");
        }

        function translate(d) {
            var scale = d3.select(this).classed('active') ? " scale(1.3)" : "";
            return "rotate(" + d.angle + " " + d.x + " " + d.y + ") " +
                "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" + scale;
        }

        function dragended() {
            d3.select(this)
                .classed('active', false)
                .attr("transform", translate)
                .attr("stroke-width", 0);
            var left = [];
            symbols.filter(function (d) {
                !check(d) && left.push(d);
            });
            repeat(left.length)
        }

        function repeat(stop) {
            d3.select('.text-effect').style('display', stop ? 'none' : 'block')

            var transition = symbols.transition()
                .attr("fill", function (d) {
                    return check(d) ? d.color : "gray"
                });
            
            if (stop)
                return;

            transition
                .attr('fill', function () {
                    return color(Math.random() * 10);
                })
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .duration(1000)
                .attr('fill', function () {
                    return color(Math.random() * 10);
                })
                .on('end', function () {
                    repeat(false)
                })


        }

        function check(d) {
            return d.x < 500 && d.x > 300 && d.y < 450 && d.y > 75;
        }
    }

    function l(x, y) {
        return "L" + p(x, y)
    }

    function m(x, y) {
        return "M" + p(x, y)
    }

    function p(x, y) {
        return (c[0] + x) + "," + (c[1] + y) + " ";
    }

    function filter_smoothMin(id) {
        // https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/03/10/creative-gooey-effects/
        var filter = defs.append('filter')
            .attr('id', id);

        filter.append('feGaussianBlur')
            .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
            .attr('stdDeviation', '3')
            //to fix safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295043/svg-gaussian-blur-in-safari-unexpectedly-lightens-image
            .attr('color-interpolation-filters', 'sRGB')
            .attr('result', 'blur');

        filter.append('feColorMatrix')
            .attr('in', 'blur')
            .attr('mode', 'matrix')
            .attr('values', '1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9')
    }

    function filter_3d(id) {
        // https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGFilterPrimer12/
        var filter = defs.append('filter')
            .attr('id', id)
            .attr('filterUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', 0)
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);

        filter.append('feGaussianBlur')
            .attr('in', 'SourceAlpha')
            .attr('stdDeviation', 4)
            .attr('result', "blur");

        filter.append('feSpecularLighting')
            .attr('in', 'blur')
            .attr('surfaceScale', 5)
            .attr('specularConstant', .75)
            .attr('specularExponent', 20)
            .attr('lighting-color', "#bbbbbb")
            .attr('result', "specOut")
            .append('fePointLight')
            .attr('x', -5000)
            .attr('y', -10000)
            .attr('z', 20000);

        filter.append('feComposite')
            .attr('in', 'specOut')
            .attr('in2', 'SourceAlpha')
            .attr('operator', 'in')
            .attr('result', "specOut");

        filter.append('feComposite')
            .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
            .attr('in2', 'specOut')
            .attr('operator', 'arithmetic')
            .attr('k1', 0)
            .attr('k2', 1)
            .attr('k3', 1)
            .attr('k4', 0)
            .attr('result', "litPaint");
    }

    function appendSvg() {
        return d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .style('margin-left', 'calc(50vw - ' + w / 2 + 'px)')
            .style('margin-top', 'calc(50vh - ' + h / 2 + 'px)')
            .style('background-color', 'steelblue')
            .attr('width', w).attr('height', h)
            .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h)
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT планирую сделать мини игру, где надо нарядить ёлочку и тогда только начнётся анимация, вот только я уехал в Выборг на пару дней, может что подправлю с мобилы

Comment: Красиво. Ёще бы надпись "Вы выиграли!" :)

Comment: Всем спасибо, за плюсы и за вознаграждение, не зря старался

Comment: @StrangerintheQ было бы ещё лучше, если бы вы убрали свой комментарий из головного поста, а то несведущий человек не так поймет ваши пассажи, насчет того, что других плюсуют, а не только вас

Comment: @Stranger in the Q тут можно поиграть в мини игру ?

Comment: @Leks игрушки перетащить на елочку)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q а понял, я их по снегу таскал туда сюда :)

Answer (score 16):

Остальное делать время нет...если будет время до рисую до конца весь мультик как я и задумал

```css
.tree {
  fill: url(#pattern);
}

.top-star {
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: yellow
}

.star-tree {
  opacity: .8;
  paint-order: markers stroke fill;
}

.tree-line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e09a11;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.26499999, 0.52999997;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0
}

.fill-gray {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.green {
  fill: #00ff00;
}

.blue {
  fill: #0000ff;
}

.pink {
  fill: #ff5555;
}

.red {
  fill: #ff0000;
}

</style><style>.tree-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.red,
.r1,
.r2,
.r3,
.r4,
.r5 {
  animation: scale 5s linear infinite;
}

.r1 {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

.r2 {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.r3 {
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

.r4 {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.r5 {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    fill: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    fill: orange;
  }
  60% {
    fill: blue;
  }
  to {
    fill: green;
  }
}

.op1,
.op2 {
  animation: opacity 10s linear infinite;
}

.op1 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.op2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.op3 {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.multy {
  animation: draw 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    transform: matrix(0.61232376, 0, 0, 0.59080494, 51.47426, 136.56321)
  }
  to {
    transform: matrix(0.61232376, 0, 0, 0.59080494, 501.47426, 136.56321)
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tree-wrapper">
    <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 236 290" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern"
           class="pat"
           width="250.75568"
     height="215.5179"
     patternTransform="matrix(.18 0 0 .15 341 .54)"
     patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <g transform="matrix(3.8 0 0 3.8 -969 -116)">
    <path    class="fill-gray op3" d="m280 52 2.3-7.8-5.2-6.3 8.2-.25 4.4-6.9 2.8 7.7 7.9 2.1-6.5 5 .46 8.2-6.8-4.6z"/>
    <path    class="fill-gray op1" d="m302 82 2.3-7.8-5.2-6.3 8.2-.25 4.4-6.9 2.8 7.7 7.9 2.1-6.5 5 .46 8.2-6.8-4.6z"/>
    <ellipse class="fill-gray op2" cx="314" cy="37" rx="5.3" ry="3.7"/>
    <ellipse class="fill-gray op1" cx="304" cy="54" rx="5.3" ry="3.7"/>
    <ellipse class="fill-gray op2" cx="289" cy="66" rx="5.3" ry="3.7"/>
    <path    class="fill-gray op1" d="m259 72 2.3-7.8-5.2-6.3 8.2-.25 4.4-6.9 2.8 7.7 7.9 2.1-6.5 5 .46 8.2-6.8-4.6z" />
    <ellipse class="fill-gray op3" cx="293" cy="84" rx="5.3" ry="3.7"/>
   </g>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(13 -11)">
  <g transform="translate(-2.3 -3.8)">
   <g>
    <path class="tree"
          transform="translate(2.3 3.8)" 
    d="m-13 301c49-89 102-167 117-290 24 133 65 225 119 288-36-5.8-47-17-81-9.2-28 6.5-81 7-101 .67-19-5.7-37 5.5-54 10z"/>
    <path class="top-star" 
       transform="matrix(.58 -.028 .029 .56 179 -45)"
    d="m-147 149 6.6-16-14-10 17 1.4 5.4-16 4 17 17 .057-15 9 5.3 16-13-11z"/>
    <g transform="translate(326 6)">
      <g transform="translate(-241 -34)">
      <path class="tree-line" d="m26 89c-3.4 11-8.2 15-14 16" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m26 120c-7.4 13-17 22-28 27" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m40 147c-17 21-35 36-56 41" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m51 177c-29 35-63 53-98 70" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m82 251c-34 31-71 53-109 75"/>
      <path class="tree-line" d="m91 272c-19 21-39 41-67 48" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m101 298c-5 3.5-15 12-23 19z" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m113 311c-12 7.6-14 8.3-14 8.3l3-.76" />
     </g>
  
     <g transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 -205 -34)">
      <path class="tree-line" d="m26 89c-3.4 11-8.2 15-14 16"/>
      <path class="tree-line" d="m26 120c-7.4 13-17 22-28 27"/>
      <path class="tree-line" d="m40 147c-17 21-35 36-56 41" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m51 177c-29 35-63 53-98 70" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m82 251c-34 31-71 53-109 75"/>
      <path class="tree-line" d="m91 272c-19 21-39 41-67 48" />
      <path class="tree-line" d="m101 298c-5 3.5-15 12-23 19z"/>
      <path class="tree-line" d="m113 311c-12 7.6-14 8.3-14 8.3l3-.76"/>
     </g>
  
     <path class="star-tree green r1"
        d="m-239 106 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r2" 
        d="m-212 124 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r3" 
        d="m-262 161 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree green r4" 
        d="m-200 165 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r5" 
        d="m-183 198 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree red r1" 
        d="m-157 246 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree red r2" 
        d="m-285 215 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree blue r2" 
        d="m-298 252 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r3" 
        d="m-253 235 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r4" 
        d="m-199 229 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree red r3" 
        d="m-266 271 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree red r4" 
        d="m-216 259 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r2" 
        d="m-137 286 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree blue r5" 
        d="m-194 294 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree pink r3" 
        d="m-242 287 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree red r3" 
        d="m-305 295 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"
/>
     <path class="star-tree blue r1" 
        d="m-219 213 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree pink r5" 
        d="m-226 177 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree green r1" 
        d="m-254 196 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
     <path class="star-tree blue r2" 
        d="m-237 142 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree blue r1" 
        d="m-226 83 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z" />
     <path class="star-tree green r3" 
        d="m-178 272 3.3-8.8-6.8 6.4 5.7-7.4-8.4 4.1 7.7-5.4-9.2 1.4 8.9-2.9-9.3-1.3 9.4-.12-8.5-4 9 2.6-6.9-6.3 7.8 5.2-4.7-8.1 5.9 7.2-2.1-9.1 3.5 8.7.65-9.3.82 9.3 3.4-8.7-2 9.2 5.8-7.3-4.6 8.2 7.7-5.3-6.8 6.5 8.9-2.8-8.4 4.2 9.4-.049-9.2 1.5 9 2.7-9.3-1.3 7.8 5.2-8.5-4 5.9 7.3-6.9-6.3 3.5 8.7-4.8-8 .75 9.3-2.2-9.1-2 9.1.58-9.3z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 
 
<g class="multy" transform="matrix(.71 0 0 .68 196 112)">
   <path d="m-281 177 1.4 1.4c.79.78 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.7s-.4.85-.89 1.5c-.8 1-1.1 1.2-3 1.3-1.2.084-2.3.32-2.5.52-.48.48-1 4.3-1 7.2-.011 5.7 1.8 11 5.4 15 2 2.2 2.3 3.1 1.5 3.9-.87.87-1.9.41-4.1-1.8-4-4-6.1-9.7-6.1-17v-3.4l-2 .21c-4.3.45-6 .87-9.8 2.3-3.7 1.5-3.9 1.6-4 2.6-.14 1.5.47 2.6 1.4 2.6.42 0 1.8-.34 3.1-.76 2.9-.94 4-.73 4.7.89.4.96.78 1.2 2 1.6 1.9.48 3.8 1.7 4.4 2.9.6 1.1.35 3.4-.97 8.8-.98 4-1.8 9.6-2.3 16-.26 3.3-.32 3.3 2.7 2.2 3.3-1.1 5-2.2 7.2-4.4 2.8-2.8 4.2-5.7 6.9-13 2.5-7.4 4-11 6.3-13 4.9-6.1 13-7.2 18-2.5 3.7 3.4 4.3 11 1.1 14-3.6 4.3-8.8 3.2-8.8-1.8 0-2.1 1-3 3-2.7l1.5.21-.36-1c-.53-1.5-1.2-1.9-2.8-1.7-2.8.38-4.3 2.1-4.3 4.8.018 2.3 1.2 4.9 4 8.8 1.2 1.6 2.4 3.6 2.7 4.4 2.4 7-1.4 17-7.9 21-1.4.79-1.7 1.2-1.5 1.5.18.28.33 1.1.33 1.8.007 1.7-1.2 2.8-3.3 3.1-1.3.15-1.7.027-2.6-.72-.97-.84-1-.96-.6-2 .35-.92.35-1.2 0-1.4-.71-.45-2.5-.33-3.3.22-.66.49-.63.61 1 4 3.7 7.4 6.8 11 10 12 2.8.89 7.7.92 10 .057 3.2-.97 5.9-3.8 5.9-6.1 0-3.6-4.8-6.3-6.7-3.8-.83 1.1-.82 1.1 1.4 2.3.61.34 1.1.89 1.1 1.3 0 .76-1.4 2.2-2.1 2.2-.72-.002-2.9-1.3-3.6-2.2-1.4-1.7-.25-5.5 2.1-7 2.8-1.7 8.1.86 9.8 4.7.68 1.6.69 3.1.048 5.6-.28 1.1-.46 2-.42 2 .35.35 6.3-4.1 8.7-6.6 7.4-7.5 9.6-16 6-24-.98-2-3.2-4.4-4-4.4-.17 0-.2.94-.065 2.1.51 4.4-.94 7.6-4.2 9.3-2 1-6.8 1.1-8.8.098-1.8-.88-3.5-2.7-4.5-4.7-1.2-2.4-1.1-7.2.035-9.8 1.1-2.4 3.3-4.4 5.7-5.2 3-.99 7.6-.65 11 .77 6.3 3 10 9.3 10 18 .38 8-2.1 15-7.5 20-4.5 4.5-9.3 7.5-16 9.6-7.7 2.6-4.4 2.4-58 2.3-28-.052-50-.24-53-.44-2.4-.19-5.4-.67-6.7-1.1-2-.62-2.7-1.1-4.5-2.9-1.3-1.4-2.6-3.2-3.5-4.9-1.2-2.4-1.4-3.1-1.4-5.3-.012-2.2.12-2.8 1-4.3 1.4-2.2 3.2-3.2 6-3.2 1.6.004 2.4.21 3.5.83 2.2 1.3 3.4 4.5 2.7 7-.79 2.9-3.7 4-6.9 2.6-.93-.41-1.8-.75-1.8-.75-.53 0 2.2 4 3.9 5.8 1.8 1.9 2.4 2.2 4 2.6 1 .22 2.7.4 3.6.4h1.8l-1.3-1.8c-3-4.1-3-8.5.051-11 1.9-1.8 5.5-2.6 6.9-1.6 1.2.88 2.4 3.2 2.4 4.4 0 1.7-1.9 3.6-3.6 3.6-1.2 0-1.7-.34-2.1-1.5-.16-.46.086-.82.92-1.3.63-.38 1.3-.75 1.5-.81.22-.074.19-.47-.081-1.1-.87-1.9-4.3-.97-5.6 1.5-.77 1.5-.64 2.5.5 4.1 1.4 1.9 3.3 3 5.2 3.1 1.4.03 1.7-.13 3.5-1.9 2.4-2.4 4.5-5.4 6.8-10l1.8-3.6-.88-.58c-.55-.36-1.2-.49-1.8-.35-.81.2-.87.34-.67 1.6.18 1.2.096 1.4-.6 1.9-1.3.92-3 .74-4.2-.46-1.2-1.2-1.4-2.8-.29-3.8.74-.67.69-.68-4.9-1.1-3.1-.22-6.6-.66-7.9-.98-7.1-1.8-11-5.8-13-14-.7-2.2-.82-3.4-.81-7.6.009-4.5.088-5.1.97-7.4 1.4-3.5 3.8-7 6.7-9.5 1.8-1.6 2.8-2.8 3.6-4.5 1-2.1 1.1-2.6 1.1-5.6 0-3.9-.73-6.3-2.6-8.5-1.4-1.7-3.1-2.3-5.6-2-4.7.49-7.4 4.3-6.1 8.7.22.79.29.71.73-.83.9-3.2 3-4.8 6.3-4.8 3.5.001 5.5 2 5.5 5.6-.001 5.4-3.7 9.9-8.2 9.9-1.5-.004-4.5-.94-6.1-1.9-3.9-2.3-6.2-6.9-6.2-13-.012-7.6 4.4-14 11-16 .97-.24 1.9-.55 2.1-.69.49-.41-1-3.4-1.9-3.7-.6-.19-.67-.34-.35-.73.33-.39.12-.6-1.1-1.1-1.2-.49-1.4-.67-1-1.1.55-.55 3.9-1.4 6.7-1.7 2-.22 2-.24 1.8-1.2l-.2-.99 3.1-.15c2.2-.1 3.4-.33 4-.75 1.2-.82 3.3-.75 5.2.17l1.6.77-1.8.86c-2 .93-2.2 1.3-1.1 1.6.48.12.71.48.71 1.1 0 .74.34 1.1 1.9 1.8 3 1.5 6.4 3.9 8.1 5.7 3.6 3.9 4.8 9.2 3.8 17l-.38 3.1 1.5 1.8c.83 1 2.9 3.4 4.5 5.3l3 3.5.8-.75c1.3-1.2 3-4.9 3.6-7.9.51-2.5.53-3.6.15-9.6-.24-3.7-.32-7.3-.19-8l.24-1.3h-1.5c-1.3 0-1.7-.21-2.9-1.4-.75-.75-1.4-1.6-1.4-1.9 0-.79 1.1-.72 2.2.13 1.2.93 1.9.89 2.6-.14.52-.79.49-.99-.34-3-.5-1.2-.9-2.4-.9-2.7 0-.38-.36-.54-1.2-.54-.99 0-1.3-.19-1.7-1-.48-.92-.46-1.1.19-1.7.5-.5.68-1.1.6-1.9l-.11-1.2-.96 1.5c-1.1 1.7-4.6 5.2-6 6-.67.4-.98.93-1.1 1.9-.25 1.9-.78 2.4-2.4 2.4-1.2 0-1.6-.24-2.8-1.4-1.2-1.2-1.4-1.6-1.4-2.8 0-1.1.22-1.7.87-2.3 1-1 1.9-1.1 3.4-.31.59.31 1.1.5 1.2.44.062-.063 1.7-3.4 3.6-7.3 1.9-4 4-7.8 4.6-8.5s1.9-1.7 2.9-2.3c1.8-1 2-1 6.7-1 5.8.011 6.7.35 7.9 3.1.44 1 .9 2.1 1 2.4.17.5.4.54 1.5.24 1.5-.43 2.2.051 3.3 2.3.96 2 .9 2.7-.34 4.2-.58.73-.98 1.4-.89 1.6.09.15.65.47 1.2.71.71.3 1 .62.89.96-.73 1.9-.65 2.1.92 2.8 1.9.86 2 .94 4 5.3 1.4 3.1 1.7 4.1 1.9 6.7.14 1.7.37 3.3.51 3.5.41.67 2.5.48 3.5-.32 1.1-.88 1.2-1.8.19-3.2l-.74-1 1.3.61c1.2.55 1.3.73 1.2 1.9-.1 1.2-.063 1.2 1.1 1.3.68.023 1.7.25 2.3.51 1.1.45 1.2.41 2.4-.61 1.9-1.7 3.4-2 6.1-1.5l2.3.42 2-1.6 1.8 3.4zm-22 48c7e-4-1.4.23-5.1.52-8.2.28-3.1.45-5.7.36-5.8-.087-.087-2.5.26-5.4.78-7.9 1.4-11 1.7-13 1.5l-2.4-.2 1.7 1.5c4 3.5 7.6 6.4 10 8.3 3 2 7.3 4.6 7.8 4.6.15.002.27-1.1.27-2.6zm1.5-44c2.8-1.2 3.1-1.5 2.4-3.3-.23-.58-.36-.49-.98.71-.84 1.6-2.5 2.7-4.2 2.7-1.2.034-1.5.24-1 .72.4.4.91.28 3.7-.88z" style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:.35"/>
   <path d="m-247 164c20-12 45-21 52-22 1.5-.13 2.9-.36 3.2-.52.31-.16.75-.93.98-1.7.24-.79.89-2.5 1.5-3.7l1-2.3-1.3-.55c-2.1-.89-3.2-2.2-3.2-3.8 0-1.5.24-1.6 1.5-.65l.89.7-.17-2.2c-.18-2.3.62-5.3 1.1-4.1.11.29.4 1 .62 1.6l.42 1.1.39-1.9c.46-2.3 1.1-3.5 1.8-3.5.42 0 .48.27.29 1.3l-.25 1.3 1.5-1.2c.8-.64 1.5-1.3 1.7-1.5.11-.18.61-.33 1.1-.33.9 0 .9.005.29.97-.34.53-1.1 1.5-1.8 2.1-.74.74-1.3 1.9-1.7 3.2-.68 2.4-.72 3.4-.2 4.9l.38 1.1 2-.7c4.2-1.4 7.6-2.1 11-2.1 6.9-.005 11 .96 17 3.7 6.2 3 14 5.1 19 5.1 2.6-.006 6.3-.83 8.8-1.9 1.1-.51 3.2-1.1 4.7-1.4 4.6-.82 6-2.6 9.1-11l1.4-3.8-2.4-1.8c-4.7-3.5-6.4-5.9-7.3-10-.13-.63-.35-1.1-.51-1.1-.15 0-2.2.4-4.6.88-4.7.96-6.2 1.1-7.1.51-.44-.3-.19-.66 1.4-2.1 3.5-3.2 6.2-3.8 11-2.7 1.1.28 2 .47 2 .42.32-.32-1.3-2.6-2.2-3.1-.62-.36-4-1.4-7.6-2.2-3.6-.88-7.1-2-7.9-2.4-1.4-.81-4.9-4.3-6-6-.3-.47-2.2-2-4.3-3.4-5.6-3.9-6.5-5-6.9-8.2-.43-3.5 1.2-10 2.2-9.2.15.15.36 2.1.46 4.4.14 2.9.38 4.5.79 5.2.48.89 3 2.9 5.4 4.4.23.14.36-1.5.37-4.8.014-4.1.16-5.5.8-7.8.97-3.4 3-7.6 4.6-9.5 1-1.2 2.9-2.4 3.8-2.4.13 0 .15.87.038 1.9-.14 1.4-.53 2.4-1.3 3.5-1.4 2-2.6 4.8-3.3 7.5-.67 2.6-.7 7.4-.066 9.8.56 2.1 2.1 5.1 2.8 5.8.7.58.7.56-.12-2.1-.37-1.2-.78-2.7-.9-3.3-.32-1.6 1-4.9 2.7-6.7 1.7-1.8 3.4-2.7 10-5.1 2.7-.99 5.8-2.1 6.8-2.5 2.6-.95 3.6-.9 3.6.17 0 1.8-3.6 3.9-9.7 5.7-4.1 1.2-4.7 1.5-6 2.8-2.1 2.1-2.5 4-1.7 8.6.34 1.9.73 3.4.86 3.3.13-.15.59-1.4 1-2.7.43-1.4 1-2.8 1.3-3.3.74-1.1 2.7-2 7.6-3.5 4.1-1.2 4.4-1.4 5.9-3 .89-.97 2.1-1.9 2.7-2.1l1.1-.33v1.5c0 1.5-1.7 4.8-2.5 4.8-.64 0-.38.65.34.88 1.1.34 1.8 1.2 1.8 2.1 0 .76-.11.84-.97.63-.53-.13-1.8-.53-2.7-.89-4.1-1.5-9.6-.21-11 2.7-.44.82-1.7 5.6-1.5 5.7.066.066.97-.86 2-2s2.3-2.4 2.9-2.7c.95-.49 1.1-.48 1.8.22l.75.75-1.6 1.4c-1.8 1.5-3.1 3.9-3.1 5.4 0 1.3 1.3 2.1 5.7 3.4 3.6 1.1 4 1.5 5.4 4l.71 1.3 2.3-.21c1.3-.12 3.2-.45 4.2-.74 2.6-.7 3.7-.67 6.2.17 3 1 4.1.92 7.5-.88 1.7-.87 3.3-1.6 3.7-1.6.94 0 1.4 1.1 1.4 3.6 0 1.2.24 3 .53 4 .29.95.53 2 .53 2.3.004.65-1.3 1.2-3.9 1.5-1.3.18-2.2.63-4.1 2.2-1.3 1.1-2.5 2.1-2.6 2.3-.66 1 2.1 6.5 5 10 4 4.7 4.6 6.2 5.1 11l.22 2.3-1.8-2.8-.011 3.5c-.011 3.4-.53 6.6-1.1 6.6-.15 0-.43-.44-.61-.97-.3-.88-.37-.74-.75 1.4-.23 1.3-.68 3.1-.99 3.8-.54 1.3-.59 1.4-.97.67-.37-.69-.49-.57-1.5 1.5-1.3 2.5-3.2 4.9-4.7 5.7-1.1.59-1.2.49-.46-.93.59-1.1.36-1.3-.69-.51-.59.44-.63.68-.3 1.7.21.67 1.2 2.5 2.2 4.1 2.1 3.2 2.2 3.2 8.3 4.5 4 .83 5.2 1.5 6.2 3.7.48 1 .99 2.3 1.1 2.7.39 1.3 2.4 5.2 3.7 7.1 1.5 2.2 1.4 3.2-.48 4.8-.86.76-2.2 1.6-3 1.8-2.6.87-3.1 1.6-4.3 5.9-1.1 4.3-1.5 5-4.3 6.9-.87.59-3.8 3.2-6.5 5.9-2.7 2.6-5.8 5.4-6.9 6.1-1.7 1.1-6.8 3.8-7.2 3.8-.079 0-.064-2.1.035-4.7.13-3.4.32-4.8.7-5.3.61-.7 5-1.8 6.2-1.5 1.5.36 2.8-.39 7.8-4.7 4.7-4 5.1-4.5 5.5-5.9.23-.89.36-1.7.31-1.7-.24-.18-10 5.5-14 7.6-4.1 2.7-5.9 3.5-8.1 3.5-.87 0-1.6-.056-1.6-.12 0-.068.16-.58.36-1.1.2-.56.66-2.8 1-5 .38-2.3.9-4.2 1.2-4.5.46-.46 1.2-.48 5.4-.1 5.7.49 5.7.48 11-2.5 4.8-2.7 5.4-3.2 5.1-4.3-.12-.49-1.5-2.3-3.1-4-1.6-1.7-3.9-4.2-5-5.5l-2.1-2.4-11-.56c-6.3-.31-12-.72-13-.91-1.9-.51-2.4-1.2-2.4-3.2v-1.8l-1.3.22c-4.6.75-11 1-15 .62-7.4-.68-12-2.2-19-6.5-5.1-3-5.2-3-8.8.27-3.1 2.9-4.1 3.5-6.8 4.5-2.1.76-2.7.8-10 .72-11-.12-12 .17-18 5.5-3.9 3.8-6 5.5-11 9.1-2.1 1.4-4.1 3-4.7 3.6-1.1 1.3-.92 2.2 1.2 4.8 3.1 3.9 3.5 4.5 3.7 5.9.13.79.11 1.6-.06 1.7-.38.38-6.1 1.4-7.8 1.4l-1.3-.006-2-4.6c-2.5-5.6-2.9-7.2-2.4-9.8.7-3.8 1.1-4.8 1.7-4.5.32.12 1.2.31 2.1.43 1.3.17 1.7.041 3-.85.85-.58 2.5-1.6 3.8-2.2 1.2-.61 2.8-1.7 3.6-2.5 2.6-2.7 5.1-8.7 6.8-16l.79-3.6 2.3-.012c5.8-.031 11-1.9 14-4.7 1.3-1.5 3.5-5.5 3.2-5.8-.31-.31-8.4.99-12 2-7.1 1.8-77 36-84 40 0 0 17-13 42-24z" style="fill:#c87137;stroke-width:.35"/>
  </g>
</svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Снегопад

Продолжу делать елку — рандомная генерация снежинок. Даже получилось сделать её адаптивной.

**<sub>Смотреть в полноэкранном режиме</sub>**

```js
url = ["https://ya-webdesign.com/images/5-point-snowflake-png-3.png", "https://www.nextibs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2744.png", "https://www.shareicon.net/download/2015/09/08/97611_snowflake_512x512.png", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/H/p/E/a/z/blue-snowflake-md.png", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/30/13/05/flake-1070310_960_720.png"];  
function generate(){
  var ran_bot = 0;
  var ran_top = $(window).width()-50;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * ran_top) + ran_bot;
  var rand = url[Math.floor(Math.random() * url.length)];
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("height", "100px");
  img.setAttribute("src", rand);
  img.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0.7; animation: fall 3s ease-in; position: absolute; top: -100px; left: " + random + "px");
  $("body").append(img);
  setTimeout(generate, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 100);
}
generate();
```

```css
@keyframes fall{
  from{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
}
body{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Неплохо по моему мнению получилось.

Comment: @0xdb Это только начало...

Comment: Начало? Ну да, до следующего НГ ещё время есть, успехов.

Comment: @Ver Nick says Reinstate Monica тут у Вас если подождать вмести снежинками, файл не загруженный летает, какой понимаю праздник в самом разгаре ?

Answer (score 14):

### О конкурсе

А давайте оживим обычные, рутинные времена проведения конкурсов.
 Накануне Новый год! Самый любимый и весёлый праздник в году. Когда все надеются и ждут чего-то хорошего.
 Наш конкурс предпраздничный и поэтому  можно отойти  от сложившихся традиций проведения конкурсов. Когда идёт жёсткая конкуретная борьба, а порою соперники отходят от правил `фейр-плей`
 До последнего момента не ясно, кого выберут победителем. Каждый участник конкурса надеется, что выберут его ответ и с нетерпением ждёт окончания конкурса. Наконец чей-то ответ принимается, как победивший в конкурсе. Проигравшим остается разочарование, а порою и острый негатив, если они считали и продолжают считать свой ответ лучше, чем выбранный ответ.

*Как сделать, чтобы наш предновогодний конкурс не был похож на обычный, рабочий сценарий?*

**Предлагаю разрешить каждому участнику от одной до трёх конкурсных попыток в отдельных постах.**

Что это даст?

- Во-первых начинать можно прямо сейчас и не тянуть до последнего
  конкурсного дня.
- Опубликовав первый ответ, можно увидеть реакцию и вовремя
  скорректировать себя в последующих ответах.
- В трех ответах можно более широко, разнонаправленно развернуться.

  И что греха таить, наличие трех, положительно отмеченных `постов`, смягчит горечь поражения. 
  Выиграет ведь только один конкурсант :-)

  **Как будут подводиться итоги и выбираться победитель?**

  По сумме нескольких номинаций:

  1. Эмоциональная, положительная сила воздействия анимационной сценки
  2. Оригинальность идеи и свежесть решения
  3. Лаконичность и сила хорошо прокомментированного кода
  4. Как вы, дорогие болельщики и участники воспринимаете ту или иную работу.

  Чтобы не топить конкурсный топик в комментариях, можно обсуждать, размещать свои мнения в чатах. 
  В главном чате это будет  размыто, предлагаю здесь https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Что ещё могу добавить, не решайте заранее для себя, что вы проиграете уже опубликованному ответу, не лишайте себя шанса, если уж и не выиграть, то хотя бы согреться :) Вперёд коллеги!

Answer (score 13):

### Анимация персонажа мальчика на табуретке, читающего стихи под ёлочкой

*Это внеконкурсный ответ*

```css
 .tree {
  width:100%;
 height:100%;

 outline:1px solid green;
 position:relative;
 }
 .txt1 {
position:absolute; 

top:25%;
left:5%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="tree">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1260 709"  >
       <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWPjk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="1" />
    
 <!-- Анимация появления картинки мальчика, читающего стихи под ёлочкой на табуретке  --> 
<g transform="scale(0.6) translate(-320 470)">
<image  id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChyh.png" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0" >
   <animate id="an_img"  attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="btn.click;an_img_none.end+1.5s" dur="2s"  repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>  
   <animate id="an_img_none"  attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" begin="an_fill_none.end+1s" dur="2s"  repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
 
 </image> 
   <!-- Замкнутый Контур  контейнера для стихов -->
</g>
  <path transform="scale(0.85) translate(0 170)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1025" stroke-dashoffset="1025" d="m386.6 66.7c31.1 0.1 36.2 126-18 109-41.2-12.9-75 80.3-95.1 122-20.4 42.3 56.2-122.7 4.5-122.6-68.8 0.1-65.9-1.2-154.7-1.2-42.2 0-60.4-105.3 1.2-107.6 68.5-2.6 87.2 0.5 147.8 0.3 10.2 0 33.3 0.2 41.6 0.2 15.8 0 56.7-0.2 72.8-0.1z" >
<!-- анимация прорисовки контура для стихов -->
  <animate id="an_str"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="1025;0"
   begin="an_img.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"/> 
    <!-- анимация заполнения фона контура -->  
  <animate id="an_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="transparent;white"
   begin="an_str.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"/> 
    <!-- анимация исчезновения контура-->   
  <animate id="an_str_none"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="0;1025"
    begin="an_fill_none.end"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"/>
      <!-- анимация исчезновения фона контура -->
  <animate id="an_fill_none"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="white;transparent"
   begin="an_text.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"/>
</path>
<g id="btn">
   <rect  x="0" y="10" rx="15" stroke="green" id="rec1" width="100px" height="40px" fill="greenyellow" />
    <text x="18" y="40" font-size="32"  fill="crimson"> Start </text>
 </g>
  
 
 

 
    <!-- Блок стихов -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
width="30%" height="40%" viewBox="0 40 -200 100">
   
     <!--    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" fill-opacity="1" stroke="red" style="border:1px solidred;" />  --> 
   <text transform="translate(100 175 )" style="font-size:24px;fill:#0D440D;font-family:Garamond"
     x="0"
     y="0">
     <tspan x="0" y="0">Нарядная, пушистая</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="100">К нам ёлочка пришла</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="150">И аромат душистый</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="200">Домой к нам принесла!</tspan> 
     <tspan x="0" y="250">Вокруг неё, зелёной,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="300">Мы водим хоровод,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="350">Сегодня встретим новый,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="400">Счастливый самый год!</tspan>
    <!-- Анимация движения строчек стихов -->  
    <animateMotion id="an_text"
  path="M 0 0 L 0 -400"
  begin="an_fill.end+0.5s"
  dur="10s"
  repeatCount="1"
  fill="freeze" />
    </text> 
</svg>  
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

#### С новым годом!

Для начала покажу ёлочку!
Ёлочка составлена из увеличивающихся звездочек.

<sub>**Нужно просматривать в полноэкранном режиме.**</sub>

```js
function add(){
  var height = 20; // высота ёлочки, можете её спокойно поменять.
  var f_c = 2 * height + 1; 
  var c = 1;  
  var row;
  for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
    row = "";
    row += "<div id = 'tree_row'>";
      for(var i = 0; i < ((f_c - c) / 2); i++){
        row += "<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = 'visibility: hidden'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill='#E2FA00'></path></svg>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < c; i++){
        row += "<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = '-webkit-animation-delay: " + (i - j) + "s'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill='#E2FA00'></path></svg>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < ((f_c - c) / 2); i++){
        row += "<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = 'visibility: hidden'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill='#E2FA00'></path></svg>";
      }
    row += "</div>"
    $("#tree").append(row);
    if(j % 2){
      c+=2;
    }

  }

}

add();
```

```css
#star{
 animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
  33%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  66%{
    transform: scale(2, 2);
  }
  99%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
body{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
#tree_row{
  margin-top: calc(0.1wv / 3);
} 
#tree{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left: 30%;
  width: calc(1% * 100);
  margin-right: calc(1% * 300);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

А теперь сборка всех моих ответов.

- Ёлка, звезда и снегопад собраны вместе и позиционированны.<sup><sup><sup>**(это заняло гораздо больше времени, чем кажется по словам)**</sup></sup></sup>
- Снежинкам задан эффект свечения.
- Санта! Каждые 10 секунд он будет появлятся, рассекая небесную гладь на своих санях, запряженных 5 * 2 оленями.
- Оптимизирован снегопад. Если раньше(см. мой ранний [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928105/282637) с снегопадом) после завершения анимации снежинки просто оставались наверху и приводили к тому, что через минут 5 всё лагало, теперь по завершении анимации они самоуничтожаются.
- Добавлены домики, чтобы смягчить мертвую пустоту и слой снега внизу.
- Снежинки уменьшены, их стало больше и им добавлена анимация вращения.
- Немного поправил цвета.
- Добавил красивую гирлянду сверху.
- Добавлена надпись "С Новым Годом!".

#### Ну а теперь готовая ёлка!

<sub>**Также нужен полноэкранный режим.**</sub>

```js
function add(){
  var height = 20; 
  var f_c = 2 * height + 1; 
  var c = 1;  
  for(var j = 0; j < height; j++){
    $("#tree").append("<div id = 'tree_row'>");
      for(var i = 0; i < ((f_c - c) / 2); i++){
        $("#tree").append("<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = 'visibility: hidden'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill =  '#E2FA00'></path></svg>");
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < c; i++){
        if(c != 1){
          $("#tree").append("<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = '-webkit-animation-delay: " + (i - j) + "s'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill =  '#E2FA00'></path></svg>");
        }
      }
      if(c == 1 && j == 0){
                  $("#tree").append("<div id='star_back'><svg aria-hidden='true' width='10%' height='10%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'main_star'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill='gold'></path></svg></div>");
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < ((f_c - c) / 2); i++){
        $("#tree").append("<svg aria-hidden='true' width='1%' height='1%' viewBox='0 0 18 18' id = 'star' style = 'visibility: hidden'><path d='M9 12.65l-5.29 3.63 1.82-6.15L.44 6.22l6.42-.17L9 0l2.14 6.05 6.42.17-5.1 3.9 1.83 6.16z' fill =  '#E2FA00'></path></svg>");
      }
    $("#tree").append("</div>");
    if(j % 2){
      c+=2;
    }
  }
}
url = ["https://ya-webdesign.com/images/5-point-snowflake-png-3.png", "https://www.nextibs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2744.png", "https://unixtitan.net/images/blue-snowflake-clipart-5.png"];  
function generate(){
  var ran_bot = 0;
  var ran_top = $(window).width()-100;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * ran_top) + ran_bot;
  var rand = url[Math.floor(Math.random() * url.length)];
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("height", "50px");
  img.setAttribute("src", rand);
  img.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0.7; animation: fall 3s ease-in; position: absolute; top: -100px; left: " + random + "px; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 20px lightblue ); filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 20px lightblue ); z-index: 1");
  img.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
    img.remove();
  });  
  img.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
    img.remove();
  });
  $("body").append(img);
  setTimeout(generate, Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1);
}
function garland() {
  nums = document.getElementById('nums_1').innerHTML
  if (nums == 1) {
    document.getElementById('garland').className = 'garland_1';
    document.getElementById('nums_1').innerHTML = '2'
  }
  if (nums == 2) {
    document.getElementById('garland').className = 'garland_2';
    document.getElementById('nums_1').innerHTML = '3'
  }
  if (nums == 3) {
    document.getElementById('garland').className = 'garland_3';
    document.getElementById('nums_1').innerHTML = '4'
  }
  if (nums == 4) {
    document.getElementById('garland').className = 'garland_4';
    document.getElementById('nums_1').innerHTML = '1'
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  garland()
}, 600)
generate();
add();
```

```css
#star{
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
  33%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  66%{
    transform: scale(2, 2);
  }
  99%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes rays{
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rays2{
  from{
    transform: rotate(180deg) ;
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #00003f;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#star_back {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#star_back:after, #star_back:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, black 50%, black), linear-gradient(82deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(67deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 50%, #ffed00), linear-gradient(52deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(37deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 50%, #f4c430), linear-gradient(22deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(7deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 10%, #f4c430), linear-gradient(-8deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(-23deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 50%, #f4c430), linear-gradient(-38deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(-53deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 50%, #f4c430), linear-gradient(-68deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), linear-gradient(-83deg, transparent 50%, #f4c430 50%, #f4c430), linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 50%, #00003f 50%, #00003f), radial-gradient(transparent 90%, white 10%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  height: 240px;
  width: 120px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  right: 49.5%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: rays 2s linear infinite;

}
#star_back:before {
  transform: translateX(120px) rotate(180deg);
  animation: rays2 2s linear infinite;
}
#main_star{
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px gold ); 
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 10px gold );
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#tree_top{
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes fall{
  from{
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateY(99vh) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes santa{
  0%{
      transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  }
  100%{
      transform: translateX(1000vh) translateY(-100vh);
    }
}
#santa{
  animation: santa 10s linear infinite;
  margin-left: -500px;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#house_body{
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: sandybrown;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#tree_row{
  margin-top: calc(0.1vw / 3);
}
#tree{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left: 30%;
    width: calc(1% * 100);
    margin-right: calc(1% * 300);
    z-index: 1;
}
#snow{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
#roof {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10vw solid DarkSlateGray;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20vw;
}
#window{
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-top: 2vw; 
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
#hor{
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
  top: 50%;
}
#ver{
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
    left: 50%;
}
#door{
  background-color: brown;
  height: 10vw;
  width: 4vw;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 13vw;
  bottom: 0; 
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
#handle{
  background-color: sienna;
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 0.1vw;
  margin-top: 3vw; 
}

#garland {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('http://imapo.ru/img/christmas.png');
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z- index: 99
}

#nums_1 {
  padding: 100px
}

.garland_1 {
  background-position: 0 0
}

.garland_2 {
  background-position: 0 -36px
}

.garland_3 {
  background-position: 0 -72px
}

.garland_4 {
  background-position: 0 -108px
}
#new_year{
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: calc(1vw * -15);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: animate_new_year 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate_new_year{
  25%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  75%{
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree">
</div>
<div></div>
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdwXD.png" id = "santa"></div>
<div id = "house">
  <div id="roof"></div>
  <div id="house_body">
    <div id="window">
      <div id="hor"></div>
      <div id="ver"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="door">
      <div id = "handle"></div>
    </div>
  </div></div>
<div id = "house" style="margin-left: 20vw">
  <div id="roof"></div>
  <div id="house_body" style="margin-left: 20vw">
    <div id="window">
      <div id="hor"></div>
      <div id="ver"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="door">
      <div id = "handle"></div>
    </div>
  </div></div>
<div id = "house" style="margin-left: 60vw">
  <div id="roof"></div>
  <div id="house_body" style="margin-left: 60vw">
    <div id="window">
      <div id="hor"></div>
      <div id="ver"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="door">
      <div id = "handle"></div>
    </div>
  </div></div>
<div id = "house" style="margin-left: 80vw">
  <div id="roof"></div>
  <div id="house_body" style="margin-left: 80vw">
    <div id="window">
      <div id="hor"></div>
      <div id="ver"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="door">
      <div id = "handle"></div>
    </div>
  </div></div>
<div id="snow"></div>
<div id="garland" class="garland_4">
  <div id="nums_1">1</div>
</div>
<div id = "new_year">С НОВЫМ ГОДОМ!</div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
```

Если у кого-то есть идеи по улучшению или проблема с нормальным показом — не стесняйтесь, пишите.

Comment: на мой взгляд лучше надпись на русском сделать ведь сайт для русскоговорящих :)

Comment: @Leks Но любой уважающий себя программист должен знать английский :)

Comment: это в будущем но это не точно :) К тому же тут могут быть не программисты а верстальщики  или просто мимо проходили :)

Comment: @Leks Хорошо, поправил :)

Comment: так лучше на мой взгляд а на Ваш ?

Comment: @Leks Мне тоже нравится, спасибо что напомнили )

Comment: жаль что Вы не указали год, а то бы я придрался какой 2019 скоро на дворе 2020 :))

Comment: В последнем пункте вашего списка написано Добавлена надпись "Happy New Year!". Я ее не нашел, вместо нее написано с новым годом ... Можете прокомментировать ?

Comment: @Leks Ахах, сейчас исправим :D

Answer (score 12):

### ***И не корысти ради, а лишь забавы для***

Новоиспечённый снеговичок бает сказы:

```css
html {background: 
repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #666, #222, #666, #ea8, #666, #222, #666, #8ce, #666 4%) fixed; }
body {max-width: 70rem;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 1200 680" width="100%" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" 
     style="background-color:#ccc;"> 
  
  <pattern id="sneg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none">
    <rect id="rec2"  x="0" y="0" rx="15" stroke="none" 
          width="1200px" height="300px" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <!-- красим фон rec2 -->  
    <animate  id="an_fill" attributeName="fill"
             values="transparent; #dee"
             begin="an_str.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- стираем фон rec2 -->
    <animate  id="an_fill_none" attributeName="fill"
             values="#dee;transparent"
             begin="an_text.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
    <image  id="sn" opacity="0" width="10%" style="x:670; y:50;" 
            xlink:href="https://r.mtdata.ru/r480x-/u28/photo0F6D/20814230894-0/original.jpeg" />
    <!-- рисуем снежинку -->
    <animate  id="an_sn" xlink:href="#sn" 
              attributeName="opacity" values="0; 1"
             begin="an_text.begin+5s" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- стираем снежинку -->
    <animate  id="an_nosn" xlink:href="#sn" 
              attributeName="opacity" values="1; 0"
             begin="an_text.end-5s" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1"fill="freeze"/> 
    
    <text style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: italic; fill: #000;"> 
        <tspan x="100" y="350">Путь млечный тучка подпирает,  </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="400">Луну и звёзды - ночь верстает, </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="450">Закрыты глазки сном подушки,   </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="500">Под песен ласки спят игрушки.  </tspan> 
      <tspan x="100" y="550">Парят снежинки за окошком,     </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="600">Щекотят нос котам и кошкам,    </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="650">А после, покружив немножко,    </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="700">Ковром ложатся на дорожку,     </tspan>
        <tspan x="100" y="800">Укрыв дома, деревья, землю     </tspan>
        <tspan x="100" y="850">- Периной тёплой...            </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="900">- Пусть подремлют,             </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="950">Угомонившись до весны;         </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="1000">- Им тоже будут сниться сны.  </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="1100">Растут сугробы от порога,     </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="1150">Впотьмах теряется дорога,     </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="1200">А тучки - снова снег роняют,  </tspan> 
        <tspan x="100" y="1250">Снежинки - сон твой охраняют. </tspan> 
    <tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="1350">Я завтра горочку построю        </tspan> 
    <tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="1400">И бабу снежную слеплю,          </tspan> 
    <tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="1450">А после вам весь Мир открою;    </tspan> 
    <tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="1500">Ведь в нём я только вас люблю!..</tspan> 
  <!-- transform="translate(80 100 )" an_text --> 
    <!-- пишем стихи --> 
    <animateMotion  id="an_text" 
                  path="M 0 0 L 0 -1500"
                  begin="an_fill.end +.5s" dur="28s"
                  repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </text> 
    
    <!-- красим фон rec3 -->
    <rect id="rec3"  x="0" y="240" rx="15" stroke="none" 
          width="1200px" height="200px" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
    <animate  id="an_fill" attributeName="fill"
             values="transparent;#dee"
             begin="an_str.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- стираем фон rec3 -->
    <animate  id="an_fill_none" attributeName="fill"
             values="#dee;transparent"
             begin="an_text.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1"fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
  </pattern>
  
  <pattern id="god" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none">
    <rect id="rec2"  x="0" y="0" rx="15" stroke="none" 
          width="1200px" height="300px" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <!-- красим фон rec2 -->  
    <animate  id="an_fill1" attributeName="fill"
             values="transparent; #dee"
             begin="an_str1.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- стираем фон rec2 -->
    <animate  id="an_fill1_none" attributeName="fill"
             values="#dee;transparent"
             begin="an_text1.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
   
    <text style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 32px; font-style: italic; fill: #000;"> 
        <tspan x="100" y="350">А на другом краю деревни, - (через брод), </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="400">Уже шагает праздник древний...            </tspan>
      <tspan fill="#068" x="100" y="450">-Новый год-,                  </tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="500">Отнюдь, не знает заграничных яств - стол, </tspan> 
      <tspan x="100" y="550">Зато дороже всяких "царств"...            </tspan>
      <tspan fill="#080" x="100" y="600">-Лес и Дол!-                  </tspan>
  <tspan x="100" y="700">Пришли "волхвы", - Я дверь им отворил:       </tspan>
    <tspan x="100" y="750">- Озябли? (те в ответ мне стали "ухать"),    </tspan>
    <tspan x="100" y="800">- Чем Бог послал... (и самогону им налил),   </tspan> 
    <tspan x="100" y="850">На закусь - рукавом пришлось "занюхать"...   </tspan> 
<tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="950">А у соседей, что ни день - гулянка,  </tspan> 
<tspan fill="#800" x="100" y="1000">И импортная "Скатерть-Самобранка"...</tspan> 

    <!-- пишем стихи --> 
    <animateMotion  id="an_text1" 
                  path="M 0 0 L 0 -1100"
                  begin="an_fill1.end +.5s" dur="28s"
                  repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </text> 
    
    <!-- красим фон rec3 -->
    <rect id="rec3"  x="0" y="240" rx="15" stroke="none" 
          width="1200px" height="200px" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
    <animate  id="an_fill1" attributeName="fill"
             values="transparent;#dee"
             begin="an_str1.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- стираем фон rec3 -->
    <animate  id="an_fill1_none" attributeName="fill"
             values="#dee;transparent"
             begin="an_text1.end" dur="2s"
             repeatCount="1"fill="freeze"/>
    </rect>
  </pattern>
  <!-- <image xlink:href="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/10/121920-aleni.jpg" width="100%"/> --> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiuun.jpg" width="100%" />
  
  <path id="ballon" fill="url(#sneg)" 
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" 
        stroke-dasharray="2124" stroke-dashoffset="2124" 
        d="M 550 350 
           Q 600 260 500 260 
           L 400 260 A 50 50 0 1 1 400 20 
           L 1000 20 A 50 50 0 1 1 1000 260 
           L1000 260 800 260
           Q 600 260 550 350 Z" >
  </path>
  
  <path id="contur" fill="url(#god)" 
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" 
        stroke-dasharray="2124" stroke-dashoffset="2124" 
        d="M 550 350 
           Q 600 260 500 260 
           L 400 260 A 50 50 0 1 1 400 20 
           L 1000 20 A 50 50 0 1 1 1000 260 
           L1000 260 800 260
           Q 600 260 550 350 Z" >
  </path>
  <!-- рисуем контур стихов -->
  <animate  id="an_str" xlink:href="#ballon" 
            attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
           begin="btn.click +0.5s" values="2124;0" 
           dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    
  <!-- стираем контур стихов -->   
  <animate  id="an_str_none" xlink:href="#ballon" 
           attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
           begin="an_fill_none.end" values="0;2124" 
           dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  
  <!-- рисуем контур стихов про Новый год -->
  <animate  id="an_str1" xlink:href="#contur" 
            attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
           begin="btn1.click +0.5s" values="2124;0" 
           dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    
  <!-- стираем контур стихов про Новый год -->   
  <animate  id="an_str1_none" xlink:href="#contur" 
           attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
           begin="an_fill1_none.end" values="0;2124" 
           dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  
  <!-- рисуем губы -->
  <path fill="#caa" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke="#922" stroke-width="6" 
        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M 410 370 
           Q 450 415 500 375 
           Q 450 415 410 370 Z"> 
    <animate  id="an_path" attributeName="d" 
              begin="an_fill.end+3s; an_fill1.end+3s" dur="1.5s"
              keyTimes="0; .25; .5; .75; 1"
              calcMode="spline"
              keySplines="1 .5 0 1; 
                          .5 1 0 .75;
                          0 .75 1 .5;
                          .5 1 .75 0" 
              values="M 410 370 
                      Q 450 415 500 375 
                      Q 450 415 410 370 Z;
                             M 440 380 
                      Q 435 435 460 385 
                      Q 455 350 440 380 Z;
                             M 420 370 
                      Q 435 410 480 375 
                      Q 450 400 420 370 Z;
                             M 440 380 
                      Q 435 435 460 385 
                      Q 455 350 440 380 Z;
                             M 410 370 
                      Q 440 415 500 375 
                      Q 450 415 410 370 Z"
              repeatCount="15" fill="freeze"
              restart="whenNotActive"/> <!--/**/-->
  </path>
  
  <g id="btn">
    <rect id="rec1"  x="0" y="10" rx="15" width="180px" height="40px"
          style="cursor: pointer; stroke: #822; fill:greenyellow; fill-opacity: 0.8"/>
    <text x="16" y="40" font-size="32"  fill="crimson" style="cursor: pointer;"> Снежинки </text>
  </g>
  <g id="btn1">
    <rect id="rec1"  x="0" y="50" rx="15" width="180px" height="40px"
          style="cursor: pointer; stroke: #822; fill:greenyellow; fill-opacity: 0.8"/>
    <text x="16" y="80" font-size="32"  fill="crimson" style="cursor: pointer;"> Новый год </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Красиво получилось :)

Comment: @Ver Nick, - Спасибо... )))

Answer (score 11):

### Новогодний сюжет анимации

[**Live Demo**](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/ZVxvNX)

- Появляется снегурочка с подарками
- Зовет детей прочитать стихи про ёлочку
- Появляется мальчик со своим щеночком
- Читает стихи про ёлочку
- Снегурочка подходит к нему и дарит корзинку с подарками
- Снегурочка исчезает

Выражаю благодарность @Варлам-Ерофеич, который предоставил мне баллон для диалогов, улучшенной формы.

```css
.tree {
  width:100%;
 height:100%;

 outline:1px solid green;
 position:relative;
 }
 .txt1 {
position:absolute; 

top:25%;
left:5%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="tree">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1260 709"  >
  <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
   <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <path fill="white"  transform="scale(0.85) translate(0 170)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1540" stroke-dashoffset="1540" d="M 375 425 Q 450 300 375 300 L 200 300 A 50 50 0 1 1 200 125 L 600 125 A 50 50 0 1 1 600 300 Q 475 300 375 425 Z" >
   </mask>
   <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
      
    <image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWPjk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="1"   />
 
    <image id="SnowMaiden" transform="translate(750 310)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAz5g.png" 
       width="60%"    height="60%" opacity="0" >
         <!-- Анимация появления снегурочки  -->    
   <animate id="Maiden"
     attributeName="opacity"
     values="0;1"
     begin="btn.click"
     dur="2s"
     repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"/>
  <!-- Анимация движения снегурочки  -->   
            <animateTransform id="RunMaiden"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="translate"
     values="750 310; 300 310"
     begin="Maiden.end-1.2s"
     dur="2s"
     fill="freeze"
              restart="whenNotActive" />   
     
  <!-- Анимация движения снегурочки после стихов мальчика  -->   
            <animateTransform id="RunMaiden2"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="translate"
     values="300 310; 100 310"
     begin="an_fill_none.end"
     dur="2s"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive" />      
     
     
 </image>   
  <g id="MaidenWords">    
    
    <!-- Контур  для слов снегурочки -->

  <path transform="scale(0.6) translate(450 400)" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1549" stroke-dashoffset="1549" d="M 375 425 Q 450 300 375 300 L 200 300 A 50 50 0 1 1 200 125 L 600 125 A 50 50 0 1 1 600 300 Q 475 300 375 425 Z" >
<!-- анимация прорисовки контура слов снегурочки -->
  <animate id="Maiden_str"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="1549;0"
   begin="RunMaiden.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация заполнения фона контура -->  
  <animate id="Maiden_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="transparent;white"
   begin="Maiden_str.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>  
     <text id="txt1" transform="translate(400 400 )" style="font-size:24px;fill:#0D440D;font-family:Garamond; opacity:0;" 
 
     x="0"
     y="0">
     <tspan x="-10" y="-50">Дети.Кто хочет подарков?</tspan>
     <tspan x="-10" y="0">Читайте стихи про ёлочку! </tspan>
     
  </text> 
   <!-- Анимация появления текста снегурочки -->
          <animate id="text_opacity"
    xlink:href="#txt1"
     attributeName="opacity"
     values="0;1"
     dur="1s"
     begin="Maiden_fill.end"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive" /> 
      <!-- Исчезновение текста снегурочки -->
        <animate id="disWordMaiden"
      xlink:href="#MaidenWords"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="text_opacity.end+2s"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
     
 </g>
   
     <!-- Анимация появления картинки мальчика, читающего стихи под ёлочкой на табуретке  --> 
<g transform="scale(0.6) translate(-320 470)">
   <image  id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChyh.png" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0" filter="url(#shadow)"  >
     <animate id="an_img"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="0;1"
   begin="disWordMaiden.end+1s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>  
   
 </image>   
  </g>   
     <!-- Контур для стихов мальчика -->

 <path transform="scale(0.6) translate(0 200)" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1549" stroke-dashoffset="1549" d="M 375 425 Q 450 300 375 300 L 200 300 A 50 50 0 1 1 200 125 L 600 125 A 50 50 0 1 1 600 300 Q 475 300 375 425 Z" > 
<!-- анимация прорисовки контура для стихов -->
  <animate id="an_str"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="1549;0"
   begin="an_img.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация заполнения фона контура -->  
  <animate id="an_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="transparent;white"
   begin="an_str.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация исчезновения контура-->   
  <animate id="an_str_none"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="0;1549"
    begin="an_fill_none.end"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/>
      <!-- анимация исчезновения фона контура -->
  <animate id="an_fill_none"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="white;transparent"
   begin="an_text.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>
</path>  

  
<g id="btn" filter="url(#shadow)">
   <rect  x="0" y="10" rx="15" stroke="green" id="rec1" width="100px" height="40px" fill="greenyellow" />
    <text x="18" y="40" font-size="32"  fill="crimson"> Start </text>
 </g>
  
   
 
 
    <!-- Блок стихов -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
width="30%" height="40%" viewBox="0 40 -200 100">
   
    
   <text transform="translate(100 175 )" style="font-size:24px;fill:#0D440D;font-family:Garamond;
   filter:"url(#shadow);" 
 
     x="0"
     y="0">
     <tspan x="0" y="0">Нарядная, пушистая</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="100">К нам ёлочка пришла</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="150">И аромат душистый</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="200">Домой к нам принесла!</tspan> 
     <tspan x="0" y="250">Вокруг неё, зелёной,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="300">Мы водим хоровод,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="350">Сегодня встретим новый,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="400">Счастливый самый год!</tspan>
    <!-- Анимация движения строчек стихов -->  
    <animateMotion id="an_text"
  path="M 0 0 L 0 -400"
  begin="an_fill.end+0.5s"
  dur="8s"
  repeatCount="1"
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
    </text> 
</svg>   
     <!-- Корзина с подарками -->  
  <image  id="img4" transform="translate(370 480)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4BVa.png" width="30%" height="30%" opacity="0" filter="url(#shadow)"  >
    <animate id="Basket_Op"
     attributeName="opacity"
  values="0;1"
  dur="0.1s"
  begin="RunMaiden2.end"
        fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
   <!-- Анимация Корзины с подарками к мальчику -->
 <animateTransform id="Basket_Up" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="370 480; 70 480" dur="2s"  begin="Basket_Op.end" fill="freeze" /> 
 
  <!-- Анимация исчезновения снегурочки  -->    
   <animate id="No_Maiden"
     attributeName="opacity"
     xlink:href="#SnowMaiden"
     values="1;0"
     begin="Basket_Up.end-1s"
     dur="2s"
     repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"/>
  
   </image>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

### Анимация, основанная на треке `Дискотеки Авария -"Новогодняя"`

Начало анимации взято из другого моего ответа,- где мальчик читает стихи на табуретке под ёлочкой. Остальная, большая часть анимации публикуется впервые.

На мой взгляд интересно получилась анимация парочки,- зайца с гитарой и снеговика.

Применена  техника совместной анимации, которая позволила с малым количеством кода реализовать алгоритм сложных совместных движений двух персонажей.

- С  1:14 начинаются анимационные эффекты текста
- С 2:11 - начинается прилёт на самолёте пьяненького, но весёлого Деда Мороза, который по пути с Камчатки потерял снегурочку или она сама потерялась :)

  Я попытался  приблизить музыкальное сопровождение, темп и смысловую нагрузку трека к анимации.

```css
 .tree {
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
 }
 .txt1 {
position:absolute; 

top:25%;
left:5%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="tree">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1260 709"  >
  <defs>
      <mask id="msk1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" >
        <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0"  width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
  <circle cx="600" cy="350" r="1" fill="black" stroke-width="70" stroke="yellow"  >
     <animate id="no_Princess" attributeName="r" values="1;350;350;1000" dur="7s"   restart="whenNotActive"  fill="freeze" />
  </circle>   
    </mask>
   <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
      
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWPjk.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="1"   />

<image id="Princess" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/u50yb.jpg" transform="translate(-120 0) scale(1.2 1)" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" >
      
 </image> 
   <!-- Анимация текста Новый Год!   --> 
   
   <path id="NY_path" d="m1207.8 682.9c0 0 24.8-274.1 4.6-497.1C1193.5-23.4 777.1 18.3 579.3 97.4 360.1 185.1 336 782.2 139.1 652.1-3.1 558.3 41.8 317.2 53.1 95.6c3.9-75.7 19.5 7.8 250.5 6.4 235.6-1.5 261-34.5 261-34.5" style="fill:none;stroke:none"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="52" font-weght="900" fill="gold" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" filter="url(#shadow)"  opacity="0" >
  <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="0%" xlink:href="#NY_path"><tspan dx="0" dy="-2">С Новым 2019 годом!</tspan>
 <!-- Движение фразы вдоль кривой линии begin ="80s" -->  
  <animate id="NY_move" 
   begin ="80s"
   dur="10s"
   repeatCount="1"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="0%;9%;9%;9%;73%;73%;73%;92%;92%"
   fill="freeze"/> 
   </textPath> 
   <!-- Появление Нового Года --> 
   <!--NY_move.begin-->
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="NY_move.begin" dur="0.1s" values="0;1" fill="freeze" /> 
   <!-- Перемещение текста-->
  <animateTransform id="text_Up2" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0;120 20;-40 -20;120 60;-40 60;120 0;-20 80;120 80;0 0" dur="3.5s"  begin="NY_move.end;98.5s;106;114.5s" repeatCount="1" /> 
   <!-- Увеличение текста-->
  <animateTransform id="text_scale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" calcMode="discrete" values="1;1.2;1.3;1.4;1.5;2;2;2;2;1.5;1.4;1.3;1.2;1" dur="5s"  begin="text_Up2.end" repeatCount="1" /> 
  <set id="red" attributeName="fill" to="red" begin="98.5s" />
  <set id="lime" attributeName="fill" to="lime" begin="106s" />
  <set id="purple" attributeName="fill" to="purple" begin="114.5s" />
  <animateTransform id="Scale_purple" attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="1.5s" from="1" to="2" begin="114.5s" fill="freeze" />

</text>
  <!-- Анимация самолёта Деда мороза  -->
    <path id="path1" d="m590 38.6c0 0 436.3-46.4 600.7-5.8 40.8 10.1 21.2 56.9 2.2 63-103.1 33.1-271.3 103.3-324.8 9.1-9.3-16.4 12.7-41.3 30.4-47.8 108.3-39.6 335.3-12 330.3 103.2-8 182.6-547.1-65.1-535.7 117.3 11 176 483.5-123.1 527 47.8 23.8 93.7-241.2 160.8-241.2 160.8v0" style="fill:none;stroke:none"/>


<image  id="fly"   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnNmf.png" width="2%" height="2%"  opacity="1" >
  <animateMotion id="MotionHal" begin="140s" dur="24s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse"   >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path1" />
    </animateMotion> 
 <animateTransform id="an_fly" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="140s" dur="25s" values="1;2;2;2;4;4;4;7;7;8;8;9;9;10;11;12" fill="freeze" /> 
 <animate id="no_fly" attributeName="opacity" begin="an_fly.end" dur="3.5s" values="1;0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
  
</image>    

   <!-- Дед мороз -->
<image id="Ded_Moroz" transform="translate(650 300) scale(1 1)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCvNN.png" width="60%" height="60%" opacity="0">
  <animate id="Yes_Ded" attributeName="opacity" begin="no_fly.end" dur="2.5s" values="0;1" 
      repeatCount="1"    fill="freeze" /> 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="Yes_Ded.end+1s" values="650 300; 600 350;600 300;600 350;650  300;650 350;650 300" dur="2.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />   
  
  </image>
  
     <!-- Анимация снеговика  --> 
        <image  id="Snowman" transform="translate(970 480) scale(0.8 0.8)" x="0" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbefD.png" width="40%" height="40%"  opacity="0"  filter="url(#shadow)" >
    <animateTransform id="Snowman_Up" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="750 455;755 425;760 415;755 435;750 455" dur="0.5s"  begin="zayka_Up.begin+4.5s;Snowman_Up2.end" repeatCount="11" /> 
   <animate attributeName="x" begin="zayka_Up.begin+4.5s"  dur="2.5s" values="0;50;70;100;70;50;50;0" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="zayka_Up.begin+4.5s" dur="4.5s" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
   <!-- Анимация снеговика + заец  -->
   <animateTransform id="Snowman_Up2" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="270 450;275 430;280 410;275 430;270 450" dur="0.5s"  begin="Snowman_Up.end" repeatCount="11" /> 
   
    
  </image>
 
 <!-- Анимация появления снегурочки  -->
         
   <image id="SnowMaiden" transform="translate(750 310)"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAz5g.png" 
       width="60%"    height="60%" opacity="0" >
             
   <animate id="Maiden"
     attributeName="opacity"
     values="0;1"
     begin="no_Princess.end-0.5s"
     dur="2s"
     repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"/>
  <!-- Анимация движения снегурочки  -->   
            <animateTransform id="RunMaiden"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="translate"
     values="750 310; 300 310"
     begin="Maiden.end"
     dur="2s"
     fill="freeze"
              restart="whenNotActive" />   
     
  <!-- Анимация движения снегурочки после стихов мальчика  -->   
            <animateTransform id="RunMaiden2"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="translate"
     values="300 310; 100 310"
     begin="an_fill_none.end"
     dur="2s"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive" />      
     
     
 </image>   
  <g id="MaidenWords">    
    
    <!-- Контур  для слов снегурочки -->

  <path transform="scale(0.9) translate(150 -70)" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1549" stroke-dashoffset="1549" d="m525 495q-45-75 0-75h105a52.5 52.5 0 1 0 0-105H390a52.5 52.5 0 1 0 0 105q75 0 135 75z" >
<!-- анимация прорисовки контура слов снегурочки -->
  <animate id="Maiden_str"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="1549;0"
   begin="RunMaiden.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация заполнения фона контура -->  
  <animate id="Maiden_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="transparent;white"
   begin="Maiden_str.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>   
   
   </path>    
     <text id="txt1" transform="translate(500 350 )" style="font-size:24px;fill:#0D440D;font-family:Garamond; opacity:0;" 
 
     x="0"
     y="0">
     <tspan x="-10" y="-100">Кто прочтёт стихи про</tspan>
     <tspan x="-10" y="-50">ёлочку. Кому подарки? </tspan>
     
  </text> 
   <!-- Анимация появления текста снегурочки -->
          <animate id="text_opacity"
    xlink:href="#txt1"
     attributeName="opacity"
     values="0;1"
     dur="1s"
     begin="Maiden_fill.end"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive" /> 
      <!-- Исчезновение текста снегурочки -->
        <animate id="disWordMaiden"
      xlink:href="#MaidenWords"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="text_opacity.end+2s"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
     
 </g>
   

     <!-- Контур для стихов мальчика -->

 <path transform="scale(0.6) translate(0 200)" filter="url(#shadow)" fill="none" stroke="white" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1549" stroke-dashoffset="1549" d="M 375 425 Q 450 300 375 300 L 200 300 A 50 50 0 1 1 200 125 L 600 125 A 50 50 0 1 1 600 300 Q 475 300 375 425 Z" > 
<!-- анимация прорисовки контура для стихов -->
  <animate id="an_str"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="1549;0"
   begin="an_img.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация заполнения фона контура -->  
  <animate id="an_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="transparent;white"
   begin="an_str.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/> 
    <!-- анимация исчезновения контура-->   
  <animate id="an_str_none"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    values="0;1549"
    begin="an_fill_none.end"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/>
      <!-- анимация исчезновения фона контура -->
  <animate id="an_fill_none"
   attributeName="fill"
   values="white;transparent"
   begin="an_text.end"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>
</path>  

     <!-- Блок стихов -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
width="30%" height="40%" viewBox="0 40 -200 100">
   
    
   <text transform="translate(120 175 )" style="font-size:24px;fill:#0D440D;font-family:Garamond;
   filter:"url(#shadow);" 
 
     x="0"
     y="0">
     <tspan x="0" y="0">Нарядная, пушистая</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="100">К нам ёлочка пришла</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="150">И аромат душистый</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="200">Домой к нам принесла!</tspan> 
     <tspan x="0" y="250">Вокруг неё, зелёной,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="300">Мы водим хоровод,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="350">Сегодня встретим новый,</tspan>
     <tspan x="0" y="400">Счастливый самый год!</tspan>
    <!-- Анимация движения строчек стихов -->  
    <animateMotion id="an_text"
  path="M 0 0 L 0 -400"
  begin="an_fill.end+0.5s"
  dur="8s"
  repeatCount="1"
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
    </text> 
</svg>   
     <!-- Анимация появления картинки мальчика, читающего стихи под ёлочкой на табуретке  --> 
<g transform="scale(0.6) translate(-320 470)">
   <image  id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChyh.png" width="100%" height="100%" opacity="0" filter="url(#shadow)"  >
     <animate id="an_img"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="0;1"
   begin="disWordMaiden.end+1s"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>  
   
 </image>   
  </g>   
     <!-- Корзина с подарками -->  
  <image  id="img4" transform="translate(370 480)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4BVa.png" width="30%" height="30%" opacity="0" filter="url(#shadow)"  >
    <animate id="Basket_Op"
     attributeName="opacity"
  values="0;1"
  dur="0.1s"
  begin="RunMaiden2.end"
        fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
   <!-- Анимация Корзины с подарками к мальчику -->
 <animateTransform id="Basket_Up" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="370 480;150 240; 70 480" dur="2s"  begin="Basket_Op.end" fill="freeze" /> 
 
  <!-- Анимация исчезновения снегурочки  -->    
   <animate id="No_Maiden"
     attributeName="opacity"
     xlink:href="#SnowMaiden"
     values="1;0"
     begin="Basket_Up.end-1.5s"
     dur="2s"
     repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"/>
  
   </image>    
       
                <!-- Анимация зайчика с гитарой  --> 
     <image  id="zayka" transform="translate(270 450) scale(1 1)" x="0" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xzEW.png" width="40%" height="40%"
             opacity="0"  filter="url(#shadow)" >
    <animateTransform id="zayka_Up" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="270 450;275 430;280 410;275 430;270 450" dur="0.5s"  begin="RunMaiden2.end" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   <animate attributeName="x" begin="RunMaiden2.end" dur="2.5s" values="0;50;70;100;70;50;50;0" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="RunMaiden2.end" dur="1.5s" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
  
   
    
  </image>
  
 </svg>
</div>
<audio src="https://svg-art.ru/files/diskoteka_avariya_novogodnyaya.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```