# Анимация растровой картинки самолёта вдоль svg пути

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, анимация

Для реализации сценки полета самолёта с Дедом морозом на борту я нашел два растровых изображения :

Наряженная ёлочка в зимнем лесу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и изображение Деда Мороза с подарками в самолёте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В векторном редакторе я нарисовал траекторию движения самолёта и совместил её с растровым изображением ёлки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код трассы полёта самолёта:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1680 1050">

   <path id="path1" d="m1648.6 24.4c0 0-341.5 179.4-456.4 327.2-102.2 131.4-97.5 174.6-169 242.2-125.1 118.5-275.2 220.3-439.5 272.1-61.6 19.4-193.6 11-193.6 11v0" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#28f10a"/>
</svg>
```

Как реализовать анимацию самолёта вдоль этой трассы и приземление его на лесную полянку около ёлочки.

Comment: Ни чё у вас творчество попёрло .. :))

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский это уже не творчество, а ремесло. Творчество было на конкурсе.. А это вариация фрагмента той конкурсной анимашки - прилёта деда Мороза, которая начинается с 2:11сек https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/930301/28748 Видимо, ту анимашку никто дальше 10 секунды не смотрел

Comment: Саша я до конца смотрел ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Ну в этом случае видел же? :) самолётик с дедом морозом

Answer (score 5):

Добавляем растровую картинку зимнего леса в векторный редактор и рисуем путь повторяющий, заданную трассу полёта самолёта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Узловые точки добавляем инструментом - `рисовать кривые Безье`(на рисунке цифра 1 )

   2. Выделяем узлы
   3. делаем их автоматически сглаженными. Рычагами управления узловых точек корректируем форму кривой.

      - Сохраняем в файл svg и берем из него формулу патча.
      - Создаем новый файл svg в который копируем полученный патч трассы
        самолёта и с помощью тегов `<image>` добавляем изображения.
      - Добавляем команды анимации перемещения самолёта вдоль трассы и
        анимацию увеличения самолёта по мере приближения к концу пути:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1680 1050" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBRad.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />

   
   <path id="path1" d="m1648.6 24.4c0 0-341.5 179.4-456.4 327.2-102.2 131.4-97.5 174.6-169 242.2-125.1 118.5-275.2 220.3-439.5 272.1-61.6 19.4-193.6 11-193.6 11v0" style="fill:none;stroke-opacity:0.9;stroke-width:2;stroke:none"/>
    

<image  id="fly"   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnNmf.png" width="2%" height="2%"  opacity="1" >
 <!-- Анимация полёта самолёта по траектории -->
  <animateMotion id="MotionHal"
     begin="0s"
     dur="24s"
     fill="freeze"
     rotate="auto-reverse">
    <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
   </animateMotion> 
   <!-- Анимация увеличения самолёта -->
     <animateTransform id="an_fly"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="scale"
        begin="0s"
        dur="25s"
        values="1;2;2;2;4;6;8;9"
        fill="freeze" /> 
 </image>    
  
</svg>
```

**многократный повтор**

Добавляем в команды анимации - `repeatCount="indefinite"`

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1680 1050" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

  
 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBRad.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />

   
   <path id="path1" d="m1648.6 24.4c0 0-341.5 179.4-456.4 327.2-102.2 131.4-97.5 174.6-169 242.2-125.1 118.5-275.2 220.3-439.5 272.1-61.6 19.4-193.6 11-193.6 11v0" style="fill:none;stroke-opacity:0.9;stroke-width:2;stroke:none"/>
    

<image  id="fly"   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnNmf.png" width="2%" height="2%"  opacity="1" >
   
   
 <animateMotion id="MotionHal" begin="0s;finish_fly.end" dur="24s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto-reverse" repeatCount="1"  >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path1" />
    </animateMotion> 
 <animateTransform id="an_fly" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="0s;finish_fly.end" dur="24s" values="1;2;2;2;4;6;8;9" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
  <animateTransform id="finish_fly" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="an_fly.end" dur="1s" values="100 400;100 400" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
</image>    
  
</svg>  
</div>
```