# Совмещение изображений с нескольких камер или дублирование изображения с одной камеры со смещением

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Прошу помочь в создании эффекта множественного "раздвоения" изображения с Unity камеры.
На сцене есть камера и есть объект, допустим куб. Необходимо "размножить" объект при отрисовке. В приложенных изображениях показано исходное состояние и желаемое на экране. Прошу не предлагать дублирование объекта, ведь это ещё более ресурсозатратно, как я полагаю.

Прошу ваших идей и предложений!

**UPD:** Поясняю: В исходном состоянии на сцене есть одна камера и один объект-куб. Камера направлена на куб. Необходимо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку объект "раздваивался"/множился (не знаю как ещё сказать), но при этом на сцене оставался в одном экземпляре.

Вижу всего 2 возможных подхода:

1. Создать ещё столько камер сколько должно быть объектов, разместить их с заданным шагом друг от друга и объединить изображение с них в одно общее, но, на сколько мне известно это резко понижает производительность т.к. рендеринг происходит для каждой из камер.
2. Как второй вариант могу предположить, что подобное можно сделать с помощью вершинного или геометрического шейдера. Тогда и камера одна и объект на сцене один.

**Рисунок 1. Пример сцены без эффекта**
[image: Рисунок 1. Пример сцены без эффекта]
**Рисунок 2. Пример сцены с эффектом** (2 "камеры")
[image: Рисунок 2. Пример сцены c эффектом]
**Рисунок 3. Пример сцены с эффектом** (3 "камеры")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Рисунок 4. Пример сцены с эффектом** (5 "камер")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: размыть надо только куб и его тень или всю картинку?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не размыть! А размножить объект с заданным шагом между его копиями. Но именно во время отрисовки, а не создавать его копии на сцене.

Comment: куб  или всю сцену? по горизонтали? что с тенью должно стать?

Comment: такой пост процессинг эффект где все повторяется легко сделать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, всю сцену. Тени как таковой и не будет. Прошу описать вариант и с ней и без неё, если возможно. Либо, хотя бы дать ссылки на литературу. Не только по горизонтали и по вертикали и по диагонали :)

Comment: я все равно не пойму что Вы хотите и как это должно в итоге выглядеть, я сейчас не у компа, доберусь - скину Вам пример кода того, что я имею в виду.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, добавил картинок, может понятнее будет...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, Вам нужен пост-процессинг шейдер, который я и сделал:

Весь фокус вот тут, смешиваем вместе N картинок со смещением по горизонтали в экранных координатах:

```
for (int c = -_Count; c < _Count+1 ; c++)
    col += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(i.uv.x-d*c, i.uv.y))/(_Count*2+1);
```

если потребуются объяснения пишите в комментах.

---

Код шейдера целиком:

```
Shader "Copier" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Count ("Count", Int) = 2
        _Offset ("Offset", Float) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _Offset;
            int _Count;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 col = 0;
                float d = _Offset/100;

                if (_Count < 0)
                    return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                for (int c = -_Count; c < _Count+1 ; c++)
                    col += tex2D(_MainTex, float2(i.uv.x-d*c, i.uv.y))/(_Count*2+1);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

---

Свойства материала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

и скрипт, его нужно повесить на камеру и в нем сослаться на материал с шейдером:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PostProcessingEffect : SceneViewFilter {

 public Material material;

 void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
   Graphics.Blit (source, destination, material);
 }
}
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PS: я сделал чтобы копий всегда было нечетное число, так было проще, могу сделать поддержку черного числа копий**

Comment: Это именно то, что нужно! Код понятный. А так же хотелось бы увидеть вариант для чётного количества. Для начала попробую сам изменить, но надеюсь Вы приложите свой вариант изменения. Хотелось бы сравнить. А то вдруг напишу коряво.

Comment: Как я понял, поскольку материал вешается на камеру, то он действует на всю сцену, на всё что попадает в камеру, так? А если материал применить к конкретному объекту, то он будет работать так же, но только для этого объекта или вообще не будет работать?

Comment: @GoodSimon первое утверждение верно, шейдер не работает со сценой, он берет кадр и шлепает его несколько раз на экран, со сещением

Comment: @GoodSimon Вы кстати поняли почему я изначально в комменте написал размыть?

Comment: По поводу размытия. Предполагаю, что из-за схожести визуального эффекта:) 
Что на счёт того, чтобы применять такой эффект только к одному из объектов на сцене? Наверное тут уже нужен совсем другой подход, да?

Comment: @GoodSimon  блюр устроен точно так же, только там копий больше и не по одной оси, про один объект - нет, можно примерно то же смое сделать и с одним объектом, я и не такое дорисовывал во фрагментном шейдере к существующей сцене

Comment: @GoodSimon вот залил на ютюб =) https://youtu.be/D0dtbADIz3k

Comment: Посмотрел, видео. У Вас получился действительно классный эффект!
Он сделан с помощью фрагментного шейдера? Интересно - как? Во фрагментном шейдере мы имеем доступ только к текстуре или это не так? Может Вам написать статью на Хабре о своём опыте? С удовольствием почитал бы :) Можете подсказать литературу?

Comment: @GoodSimon Все верно, это объекта нет в сцене, он посчитан о добавлен полностью в шейдере, при помощи трассировки лучей

Comment: @GoodSimon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j-LT1-9zME вот это так же сделано

Comment: я вот тут делал пример для конкурса и распинался как это работает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/927012#927012